# Kotlin Functional Vector Dot Product

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, linear-algebra

I have a Kotlin Vector class that includes a function to calculate the dot product of two Vectors:

```
class Vector(val values: Array<Double>) {

    fun dot(v: Vector): Double {
        require(this.values.size == v.values.size)
        var product = 0.0
        for (i in this.values.indices) {
            product += this.values[i] * v.values[i]
        }
        return product
    }
}
```

I'd like to express the dot product of two vectors in a functional style.  Fold would initialize, but I don't see how to make it work with two arrays.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is accurate, but it's not that efficient: zipping the arrays together allocates a new list, copies both source arrays, and produces a `Pair` for each data element, all of which are disposed soon after. This more than doubles memory consumption.

I don't think your code above is really that bad, although I'd probably implement it as an extension function on `DoubleArray`:

```kotlin
infix fun DoubleArray.dot(other: DoubleArray): Double {
  var out = 0.0
  for (i in 0 until size) out += this[i] * other[i]
  return out
}
```

This is purely functional in that it has no side effects, and always returns the same result given the same inputs. Your consumers will never know your little `for` loop secret.

You *can* do it with `foldIndexed` though, for that slick, functional Kotlin styling:

```kotlin
infix fun DoubleArray.dot(other: DoubleArray) =
   foldIndexed(0.0) { i, acc, cur -> acc + cur * other[i] }
```

I find this slightly harder to read though (all those `cur`s and `acc`s, plus an odd floating `0.0`); and under the hood, `foldIndexed` is just using a `for` loop anyway.

Comment: You're right about the performance. I tested on a 1M entry array, and your loop and `foldedIndex` are about 18x faster (~90ms vs ~5ms). The loop answer is exactly what the OP said they didn't want to do, but +1 for `foldIndexed`.

Comment: PS I fixed a bug in your loop condition, a good example of why sticking to the built in functions is better :)

Comment: Thanks @AdamMillerchip for the profiling and correction! Honestly, I'm surprised they weren't both wrong. In my own code (I got here because I was looking up dot product) I went with `foldIndexed` so fortunately I didn't retain my own bug...

Comment: Thanks to another anonymous commenter who pointed out that in my first block I had accidentally added the vector constituents, instead of multiplying them. This is now corrected.

Answer (score 3):

I would [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) the the two arrays, and then use [`sumByDouble`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by-double.html):

```
fun dot(v: Vector): Double = values
    .apply { require(size == v.values.size) }
    .zip(v.values)
    .sumByDouble { (a, b) -> a * b }
```

---

Sidenote: If you're on the JVM, you could [consider using `DoubleArray` instead of `Array<Double>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391973/kotlin-use-arraydouble-or-doublearray). The former will be represented as a `double[]` on the JVM, rather than an array of boxed `Double`s.

Comment: Thank you so much for you advice and code.  I greatly appreciate both.

Answer (score 2):

You can zip them with a transform function and then sum the total:

```
return values.asSequence().zip(v.values.asSequence()) { a, b -> a * b }.sum()
```

or

```
return values.zip(v.values) { a, b -> a * b }.sum()
```

or

```
return values.zip(v.values, Double::times).sum()
```