# Java Map did not accept "boolean"

Tags: java, dictionary

Maybe is a newbie question, but I don't understand why when I try to do something like `Map<String, boolean>` my IDE screams saying "Syntax error on token "boolean", Dimensions expected after this token", but with Boolean it works perfect. Can anyone explain me why is it like that? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The answer is in this more general question: [Why don't Generics support primitive types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types)

Comment: Most `Map<X, Boolean>` can be replaced by a `Set<X>`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Simply put: Java generics don't work with primitive type arguments, only classes. So in the same way, you can't use `List<int>`, only `List<Integer>`.

See the relevant [Java Generics FAQ entry](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#Are%20primitive%20types%20permitted%20as%20type%20arguments?) for more information.

Answer (score 31):

Use Boolean instead of boolean. Map can only contain objects and boolean is a primitive type not an object. Boolean is object wrapper of boolean.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to other responses, note that you can use `Map<String, Boolean>` and use them *almost* as if it were `Map<String, boolean>`. That is, you will be able to `put` and `get` `boolean`s (primitive). Look up autoboxing for explanation why this works. There are some pitfalls of using autoboxing but in simple cases it should work.