# why we cannot use double as a generic T?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types)

Why we cannot use `double` as a `T`, instead we have to use Double?

we will have compile error if using List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics type parameter must be a sub-class of `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 1):

double is not an Object,You can use Double

Comment: +1. Also, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html (it specifically mentions you cannot use primitives).

Comment: @Rachel I think the OP understands that generic types cannot be primitives. The question is: _why not?_

Comment: How is this an answer?  It doesn't explain the why at all, and the OP already knew he had to use `Double` instead.

Comment: I think the OP wants to konw 'how' but not 'WHY'.

Answer (score 0):

`double` is `primitive data type` of Java, while Generics type needs an `java.lang.Object`, and `Double` is an Object

Answer (score 0):

T must be non-primitive data type. It may seem inconvenient at first glance, but there is auto-boxing, that is you can have something like this:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
double x = 5.0d;
list.add(x);
double y = list.get(0);
```

Comment: As with @LiuwkCn's answer: this does not answer the question at all. It states the "what" (which the OP appears to have already figured out), not the "why." -1