# How to define a char stack?

Tags: java

How to define a char stack in java? For example, to create a String stack I can use such construction:

```
Stack <String> stack= new Stack <String> ();
```

But when I'm try to put char instead String I got an error:

```
Syntax error on token "char", Dimensions expected after this token
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a collection of char is pretty inefficient. (but it works) You could wrap a StringBuilder which is also a mutable collection of char.

```
class CharStack {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public void push(char ch) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }

    public char pop() {
        int last = sb.length() -1;
        char ch= sb.charAt(last);
        sb.setLength(last);
        return ch;
    }

    public int size() {
        return sb.length();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about .append() method. Is it really works faster than stack?

Comment: If you have a new Character (~ 16 bytes) and you have to add it to a Stack (4 bytes per reference) it will be much larger than just adding a char (2 bytes)  Even if you have a cached character it will be twice as big.  Stack is also thread safe which makes it slightly slower. You can add and remove char(s) in a StringBuilder without creating any garbage. (Unless the "stack" get longer)

Comment: Thanks a lot ) Then I'll use your solution

Answer (score 68):

Primitive types such as `char` cannot be used as type parameters in Java. You need to use the wrapper type:

```
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
```

Comment: As someone who has been using c++. the name convention in Java is so inconsistent.

Answer (score 14):

`char` is one of the primitive datatypes in Java, [which cannot be used in generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types). You can, however, substitute the wrapper [`java.lang.Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), as in:

```
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
```

You can assign a `Character` to a `char` or the other way around; Java will [autobox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) the value for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] stack=new char[s.length()]
```

where `s` is the string passed as function argument.

Comment: Hi Sarvesh Mishra and welcome on SO!
This question has already been answered, please refrain from answering questions that have already been answered if your answer does not improve the existing.

Comment: Just a friendly tip.. Having to explain what a variable means is a strong indicator that you should have used a more expressive name ;)

Comment: @Neuron I agree man!!Thanks for the tip:)