# Syntax error when using "DynaArray<int>" in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to write my own version of a C++ STL vector<> I want it to make a dynamically growing and shrinking list...I want to have methods for push_back, push_front, pop_back, pop_front, remove, removeAt, clear, and size...I wrote all of these with little problem and am getting no build errors or warnings, when I try to instantiate the class Eclipse tells me that its looking for Dimensions after token...so it thinks any type I send in wants to be an array of that type, for instance...

```
    DynaArray<int> Bob;
```

Here it wants the [] operator after the int.

Here is what my class presently looks like

```
    public class DynaArray<T>
{       
    int Size = 0;
    int CurrentCount = 0;
    int LastSpot = 0;
    T[] Array;

    DynaArray(int _size)
    {
        Size = _size;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    void push_back(T _element)
    {
        CurrentCount++;
        if(CurrentCount > Size)
        {
            //make a new array for double the size;
            if( Size == 0 )
            {
                Size = 2;
                Array = (T[]) new Object[Size];
            }
            else
            {
                int OldSize = Size;
                Size = Size*2;
                T[] TempArray;
                TempArray = (T[]) new Object[Size];
                int i = 0;
                for( ; i < OldSize; i++ )
                {
                    //Copy over info from Array to TempArray
                    TempArray[i] = Array[i];
                }
                Array = TempArray;
            }
        }

        //Now add the new element onto the array
        Array[LastSpot] = _element;
        LastSpot++;     

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    void push_front(T _element)
    {
        CurrentCount++;
        if( Size == 0)
        {
            Size = 2;
            Array = (T[]) new Object[Size];
            Array[0] = _element;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int OldSize = Size;
            Size = Size+1;
            T[] TempArray;
            TempArray = (T[]) new Object[Size];
            int i = 1;
            for( ; i < OldSize; i++ )
            {
                //Copy over info from Array to TempArray
                TempArray[i] = Array[i-1];              
                Array = TempArray;
                Array[0] = _element;
            }           
    }

    }

    T pop_back()
    {
        if( CurrentCount <= 0)
            return null;
        else
        {
            return Array[CurrentCount-1];
        }

    }

    T pop_front()
    {
        if( CurrentCount <= 0)
            return null;
        else
        {
            return Array[0];
        }
    }

    int size()
    {
        return CurrentCount;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    void clear()
    {
        Size = 0;
        CurrentCount = 0;
        LastSpot = 0;
        Array = (T[]) new Object[2];

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    void removeAt(int index)
    {
        T[] TempArray = (T[]) new Object[Size];
        int ArrayIndex = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < CurrentCount; i++)
        {
            if( i == index )
                continue;

            TempArray[ArrayIndex] = Array[i];
            ArrayIndex++;

        }
    }

    void remove(T _element)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < CurrentCount; i++)
        {
            //look for the element
            if( Array[i] == _element)
                removeAt(i);
        }
    }


}
```

Thanks for any help provided or if my code somehow helped you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a primitive, and as such [cannot be used with Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html). The reason for this is to [maintain the bytecode's backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types) (which was important when generics were first introduced). You must use an [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) instead.

**N.B.** unless you're doing this as an academic exercise, you can/should just use a [`List<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of your custom-implemented class.

Alternatively: use [Trove.](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Java primitives as a generic type because they are [not instances of Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types). The reason why `int[]` works is because a Java array is an object. Use the boxed `Integer` instead.