# new ArrayList<int>() failing in Java

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
List<int> intList = new ArrayList<int>();
for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++)
{
    intList.add(ints[index]);
}
```

It gives me an error...

```
Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token
```

The error occurs on the line starting with `List`. Can someone explain why I am getting the error?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Generics in Java are [not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types) to *primitive types* as in `int`. You should probably use [wrapper types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) such as `Integer`:

```
List<Integer> ints = ...
```

And, to access a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you need to use `ints.get(index)`.

Answer (score 10):

You can only use an Object type within the `<>` section, whereas you're trying to use a primitive type. Try this...

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You then need to access the values using `intList.get(index)` and `intList.set(index,value)` (and also `intList.add(value)` as you are trying to do)

Answer (score 4):

you should use Integer instead of int because lists requires object not primitive types. but u can still add element of type int to your Integer list

Answer (score 1):

You can use primitive collections available in [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/). Eclipse Collections has `List`, `Set`, `Bag` and `Map` for all primitives. The elements in the primitive collections are maintained as primitives and no boxing takes place.

You can initialize a [IntList](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/IntList.html) like this:

```
MutableIntList intList = IntLists.mutable.empty();
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.