# Generic methods don't work with 'int' type variable?

Tags: java, generics, int

I'm having some trouble with the two variables: int and Integer.
They're roughly the same, but (as shown in the code below) they don't always act the same.
Here's my problem:
This piece of code works just perfect. I've made a generic method, printArray which needs an array of any kind of variable (since it is generic) in order to work. 
Here I use the variable type Integer.
But, when I change my type of array 'getal' to int (instead of Integer), the method printArray doesn't work annymore. Why is that? Do generic methods not work with int type variables?

```
package Oefenen;

public class printArray
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Integer[] getal = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        printArray(getal);  
    }

    public static <E> void printArray (E[] intArray)
    {
        for (E element : intArray)
        {   
            System.out.printf("%s\n", element);
        }
    }
}
```

ps: If I change the generic method to a method only for int's, it does work. 
So I was thinking the problem is : Generic methods do not work with int's.
Am I

Comment: Yeah you are right. They don't work for primitive types, but only for classes.

Answer (score 10):

Generic methods only work with subtypes of Object. Integer is a sub type of Object. int is not an object but a primitive. So this is expected behaviour. This [link](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html) is quite useful

This related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types) may also be useful

Answer (score 5):

Generics works only for classes. int, as double, float, etc... are not classes

Answer (score 1):

Generics work only for real Types, int is a primitive type (like float, double, ...)

You may, however, use autoboxing, e.g.

```
int primitiveInt = 1;

// this will 'autobox' (transform) the primitive type to a real type.
Integer typedInt = primitiveInt;
```

The other way around works, too, but be aware of possible NullPointerExceptions, because a real type may be null, which is not handled by autoboxing. (a primitive type has always a default value)

Answer (score 1):

**-** Though `Generic` can be used with class, methods, variables, interface but one of the main reason of using **Generics is to make Collection Type-Safe.**

**-** `Generics` deals with **only Objects**. `int` is a **primitive** type, but `Integer` are **Wrapper Objects**. Due to `AutoBoxing` which was introduce from Java 5, you are not able to find the difference while you move from int to Integer or vice-versa.

**-** In `Collection` also when we use `Generics`, then Wrapper objects are used.