# Generic programming in Java source code

Tags: java, api, generics

Arrays and Collections are two basic api classes used by all java programmers. Both the classes were added in Java 1.2

Looking at Arrays class, there are **27 overloaded binarysearch methods** and it has no usage of Generics where as collections is updated to use generics. Where as Collections class has 2 overloaded binary search methods.

Any reason why it is done this way or am i missing any thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Java generics can only be parameterised on reference types.  `int`, `long`, etc. are primitive types.

Comment: C++ has templates support for primitives as well.. but i guess java doesnt support templates..

Comment: Related article.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types