# Code generation using string template

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I am trying to use string template to generate Pig/Hadoop code. Since I am a novice I couldn't figure it out myself. Any help will be appreciated.

I have a List of LocalDate like one show below

```
List<LocalDate> dates = Arrays.asList("20100101", "20100102").stream().map(d -> LocalDate.parse(d,formatter)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The list can have 1 dates or many dates.

If the list "dates" contains more than one element then I would like to generate:

```
SPLIT finalizedEvents INTO splitByDay_20100101 IF dataDate == 20100101,
                  INTO splitByDay_20100102 IF dataDate == 20100102, ....; // for all date in "dates" list
// similarly for all dates
// formatting substitution variable e.g. 2010/01/01 instead of 20100101 is needed
STORE splitByDay_20100101 INTO '/a/b/2010/01/01' USING AvroStorage();
STORE splitByDay_20100102 INTO '/a/b/2010/01/02' USING AvroStorage();
```

If the list "dates" contain one element only then I would like to generate (assume dates = [ 20100101] )

```
splitByDay_20100101 = FOREACH finalizedEvents GENERATE $0..;
STORE splitByDay_20100101 INTO '/a/b/2010/01/01' USING AvroStorage();
```

So far I have done something like the following but not sure how to do the conditionals

```
ST e = new ST("SPLIT finalizedEvents INTO <[dates]:{ d | IF split_<d> BY daysSinceEpoch == <d>}; separator=\", \">;");
e.add("dates", dates);
System.out.println(e.render());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with (detailed explanation below):

### Java Code:

```java
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(LocalDate.parse("20100101", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
dates.add(LocalDate.parse("20100201", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));

List<List<Character>> charListList = new ArrayList<>();
for (LocalDate date : dates) {
    List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] dateCharArray = date.toString().toCharArray();
    for (char c : dateCharArray) {
        charList.add(c);
    }
    charListList.add(charList);
}

STGroup dateGroup = new STGroupFile("./src/com/stackoverflow/DateList/dates.stg");
ST dateTemp = dateGroup.getInstanceOf("writeCode");
dateTemp.add("formattedDates", charListList);
dateTemp.add("isSingle", charListList.size() == 1);

System.out.println(dateTemp.render());
```

### StringTemplate Code (dates.stg):

```
writeCode(formattedDates, isSingle) ::= <<
<if(isSingle)><writeSingleStuff(formattedDates)>
<else><writeMultipleStuff(formattedDates)>
<endif>
<writeStoreList(formattedDates)>
>>


writeSingleStuff(date)::= "<date:{d|splitByDay_<wordReplaceWSlash(d)> = FOREACH finalizedEvents GENERATE $0..;}>"

writeMultipleStuff(rawDates)::= "SPLIT finalizedEvents <rawDates:{d|INTO splitByDay_<wordReplaceWEmpty(d)> IF dataDate == <wordReplaceWEmpty(d)>}; separator=\", \">;"

writeStoreList(formattedDates)::= "<formattedDates:{d|STORE splitByDay_<wordReplaceWEmpty(d)> INTO '/a/b/<wordReplaceWSlash(d)>' USING AvroStorage();<\n>}>"


wordReplaceWSlash(word) ::= "<word:{char|<charReplaceWSlash(char)>}>"

charReplaceWSlash(theChar) ::= <%<charReplaceWSlashMap.(theChar)>%>

charReplaceWSlashMap ::= [
    "-":"/",
    default:{<theChar>}
]


wordReplaceWEmpty(word) ::= "<word:{char|<charReplaceWEmpty(char)>}>"

charReplaceWEmpty(theChar) ::= <%<charReplaceWEmptyMap.(theChar)>%>

charReplaceWEmptyMap ::= [
    "-":"",
    default:{<theChar>}
]
```

## What the code does:

### Java Code:

```java
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(LocalDate.parse("20100101", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
dates.add(LocalDate.parse("20100201", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
```

This is a list with `LocalDates` that we wanna use as input for the templates. I formatted them with `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` so that e.g. `20100101` becomes `2010-01-01`. We need this later because we will tell StringTemplate to replace `-` with either `/` or an empty string to get the two types of date formats that we want (and I didn't find a formatter that gets `2010/01/01` in the first place).
Two different approaches would be:

- Replace `-` with `/` in Java code, not in StringTemplate. Then, we only had to replace `/` with an empty string, if we need this date format.
- add year, month and day as three different variables into the template. Then we could concatenate the strings and add `/` when we need to.

```java
List<List<Character>> charListList = new ArrayList<>();
for (LocalDate date : dates) {
    List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] dateCharArray = date.toString().toCharArray();
    for (char c : dateCharArray) {
        charList.add(c);
    }
    charListList.add(charList);
}
```

It's not very pretty that we have to do this, but:
We have to have a list (and *not* an array) of the chars of a date so that we can "iterate" over it in StringTemplate. And there is [no direct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590675/converting-char-array-to-list-in-java) to convert char[] to List. In the end, we have to put all these lists together in one list so that we can generate code for every date we have (`charListList`).

```java
STGroup dateGroup = new STGroupFile("./src/com/stackoverflow/DateList/dates.stg");
ST dateTemp = dateGroup.getInstanceOf("writeCode");
dateTemp.add("formattedDates", charListList);
dateTemp.add("isSingle", charListList.size() == 1);

System.out.println(dateTemp.render());
```

Here we fill the template with values. We have to tell StringTemplate *here* whether or not we have exactly one date in our `charListList` because StringTemplate is ([by design](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/introduction.md)) not capable of doing so.

### StringTemplateCode:

```
writeCode(formattedDates, isSingle) ::= <<
<if(isSingle)><writeSingleStuff(formattedDates)>
<else><writeMultipleStuff(formattedDates)>
<endif>
<writeStoreList(formattedDates)>
>>
```

This is the "root" template that basically just delegates the work to other templates. It handles the case distiction between one or many dates.

```
writeSingleStuff(date)::= "<date:{d|splitByDay_<wordReplaceWSlash(d)> = FOREACH finalizedEvents GENERATE $0..;}>"

writeMultipleStuff(rawDates)::= "SPLIT finalizedEvents <rawDates:{d|INTO splitByDay_<wordReplaceWEmpty(d)> IF dataDate == <wordReplaceWEmpty(d)>}; separator=\", \">;"

writeStoreList(dates)::= "<dates:{d|STORE splitByDay_<wordReplaceWEmpty(d)> INTO '/a/b/<wordReplaceWSlash(d)>' USING AvroStorage();<\n>}>"
```

With these three lines, we write the code that is specific for a single item, for mutltiple items, and the code that both have in common.
Although we know that `date` has only one item when we enter `writeSingleStuff`, we have to iterate through the list.

```
wordReplaceWSlash(word) ::= "<word:{char|<charReplaceWSlash(char)>}>"

charReplaceWSlash(theChar) ::= <%<charReplaceWSlashMap.(theChar)>%>

charReplaceWSlashMap ::= [
    "-":"/",
    default:{<theChar>}
]


wordReplaceWEmpty(word) ::= "<word:{char|<charReplaceWEmpty(char)>}>"

charReplaceWEmpty(theChar) ::= <%<charReplaceWEmptyMap.(theChar)>%>

charReplaceWEmptyMap ::= [
    "-":"",
    default:{<theChar>}
]
```

These are two groups of templates that almost do the same thing: Replace every `-` char in every "word" with either `/` or an empty string. We use a little dictionary for that that replaces every char but `-` with itself.