# Why can't I initialize a Map<int, String>?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

I want to store a set of `int`/`String` values, but the `int`s are not necessarily incremental, meaning the data can be:

```
<1, "first">, <3, "second">, <9, "third">.
```

So I'm trying to create the c# equivalent of a `Dictionary<int, string>` but it just fails to compile, saying "Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token" on the line:

```
private Map<int, String> courses;
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is? And a good alternative to creating an object as a placeholder for the `int` and `String`, then using an array to store them?

Comment: Use Integer as the key type.  It can decay to an int so it is just as useful.

Comment: Related: [Why don't Generics support primitive types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot use primitive types as generic type arguments.

Use

```
private Map<Integer, String> courses;
```

See more restrictions on Generics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html).

Dev's contribution: the [JLS specifies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) that only reference types (and wildcards) can be used as generic type arguments.

Comment: As for the why, The [Java Language Specification] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) specifies that only `ReferenceType` may be used as a Type Argument.

Comment: @Dev Thanks, gave up looking for it :p

Comment: If you don't want the overhead of boxing key values as `Integer` objects, then you can use a third-party solution. The [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) library has [TIntObjectHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TIntObjectHashMap.html) and Android has [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) (the latter only useful for Android projects, of course). However, these third-party maps don't implement the `Map` interface from the Java collections framework, since the keys are not objects.