# What is an 'ambiguous type' error in Java?

Tags: java, list, ambiguous

In the following code, I get an error from the compiler on the last line that says: 'the type List is Ambiguous' (on the line that attempts to define cgxHist list).  What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class drawr extends JPanel{

    public static int animationSpeed=470;
    public static int diameter = 50;
    hBod allHBods[];
    List<String> cgxHist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I actually wanted the list to contain integers, but when I try to 'cast' the list as such, by replacing `<String>` with `<int>`, the error on that line becomes 'Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token'.  Advice please.

Comment: You can't use `<int>`, as generics don't support primitive types. See, for example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types) for more info.

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325277/why-does-system-out-printlnnull-give-the-method-printlnchar-is-ambiguo

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that there is a `List` class in both the `java.awt` and the `java.util` package, and as you are importing all classes in those packages, the compiler doesn't know which one you mean.

So you should either not use the asterisk to import all classes at the same time (just import the ones you actually need) or instead of `List` write `java.util.List<String> cgxHist = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm learning, but it's a very slow process.

Comment: This only answers half the question. The other problem is that primitives cannot be used with generics - the OP will have to use `<Integer>` instead of `<int>`.

Answer (score 7):

```
java.awt.List

java.util.List
```

Both of these exist. You'll have to add the namespace in front to use one:

```
java.util.List<String> cgxHist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you don't, it doesn't know how to interpret the `List<T>`: is it the `awt` one or `util`? Ergo: ambiguous.