# Java error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: java, javascript, mysql

I want to do a web for upload photo to mysql with jsp code, but there is a error that I do not how to solve in the coding.

First, I have find a example "upload.html"

```
<title>Select your File to upload</title>
<form action="loading_blob.jsp" method=POST ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
Staff ID: 
<input type=text name=id>
Photo:
<input type=file name=uploadfile>

<input type=submit name=button value=upload>
</form>
```

and with the example (loading_blob.jsp) and downloaded the cos.jar and put it into tomcat->lib

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.sql.*, java.util.*, javax.servlet.*, javax.servlet.http.*, com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.*"  %>

<%
String contentType = request.getContentType();
System.out.println("Content type is :: " +contentType);


String dirname = "C:\\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\\webapps\\ROOT\\upload-example\\";
File dir = new File(dirname);
String value = "";
String fileName = "";
String filePath = "";
long size = 0;

MultipartParser mp = new MultipartParser(request, 1*1024*1024); // 10MB
Part part;
while ((part = mp.readNextPart()) != null) {
  String name = part.getName();
  if (part.isParam()) {
    // it's a parameter part
    if (name.equals("id"))
      {   
         ParamPart paramPart = (ParamPart) part;
     value = paramPart.getStringValue();
     out.println("param; name=" + name + ", value=" + value);
      }
  }
     else if (part.isFile()) {
            // it's a file part
        FilePart filePart = (FilePart) part;
        fileName = filePart.getFileName();
        if (fileName != null) {
               filePath = filePart.getFilePath();
           // the part actually contained a file
           size = filePart.writeTo(dir);
           out.println("file; name=" + name + "; filename=" + fileName +
          ", filePath=" + filePath +
          ", content type=" + filePart.getContentType() +
          ", size=" + size);
      }
      else {
        // the field did not contain a file
        out.println("file; name=" + name + "; EMPTY");
           }
    }

  }

String dirname1 = dirname + fileName;
out.println(dirname1 + size);
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
 Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db1", "root", "0000"); 

InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dirname1);

 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Update person set photo = ?, filename = ? where staff_id = ?");

ps.setBinaryStream (1, fis, size); 

ps.setString (2, fileName);
 ps.setString (3, value);
 ps.executeUpdate();
 ps.close();

 fis.close(); 

%>
```

Error statement :

```
An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /loading_blob.jsp
The type Part is ambiguous
13: long size = 0;
14: 
15: MultipartParser mp = new MultipartParser(request, 1*1024*1024); // 10MB
16: Part part;
17: while ((part = mp.readNextPart()) != null) {
18:   String name = part.getName();
19:   if (part.isParam()) {


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Thank you

Comment: Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255420/what-is-an-ambiguous-type-error-in-java

Answer (score 1):

According to @Gimby's comment. Investigated imports ;

You have two Part object. javax.servlet.http.Part and com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.Part . So you should specify which one is using.

`javax.servlet.http.Part` or `com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.Part` use like this.

Btw , try to define Part object as null.

```
MultipartParser mp = new MultipartParser(request, 1*1024*1024); // 10MB
com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.Part part = null; //Example usage , btw On the next line in while section `part = mp.readNextPart()` part shouldn't be null.
```

Comment: I don't see how that would make the type 'Part' less ambiguous to the compiler.

Comment: @Gimby yes you are right , i investigated the imports. So it has two Part object. I improved answer according to your notice , thanks.