# Java autoboxing and unboxing

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to convert and array ints to a List however every time I try I get a compilation error.

```
   List<Integer> integers = toList(draw.getToto6From49().getFirstRound());

// getFirstRound() returns int[] ;
```

and here is my to `toList` method

```
public class ArraysUtil {


 public static <T> List<T> toList(T[] ts) {
  List<T> ts1 = new ArrayList<>();
  Collections.addAll(ts1, ts);
  return ts1;
 }
}
```

java: method toList in class com.totoplay.util.ArraysUtil cannot be applied to given types;

```
  required: T[]
  found: int[]
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: int
    bound(s): java.lang.Object
```

Comment: What compilation error?

Comment: Some scientists believe it's helpful to specify your errors in your question.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel I do like your post ha ha ha ... !

Comment: `int` is not of type `T`, because `T` is a subclass of `Object` and `int` is not a subclass of `Object`.

Comment: @Adio what is this returning: draw.getToto6From49().getFirstRound() ?? int[] ? if so, look at christopher comment above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can't do that, basically. You're expecting to be able to call `toList` with a type argument of `int`, and Java doesn't allow primitives to be used as type arguments. You basically need a different method for each primitive you want to handle like this, e.g.

```
public static List<Integer> toList(int[] ts) {
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(ts.length);
  for (int i in ts) {
    list.add(i);
  }
}
```

At least, that's the case in Java 7 and before. In Java 8 it's slightly simpler:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
IntStream stream = Arrays.stream(array);
List<Integer> list = stream.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I would recommend `new ArrayList<>(ts.length);` to avoid duplicating the size of the internal array

Answer (score 0):

It's because primitive types don't play nicely with generics. All generics need to be treatable as objects, and primitives can't be. [More Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types)

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can  do this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(101); // autoboxing will work
int aValue = list.get(0); // autounboxing will work, too
```

> Specifying the Integer type in angle brackets (< Integer >), while
> creating the List object, tells the compiler that the List will hold
> object of only Integer type. This gives the compiler freedom to wrap
> and unwrap your primitive int values while you work with the List
> object
>
> *from the book: Beginning Java 8 Fundamentals*