# Generic methods with an array parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, function, generics, methods

I want to write a generic method that prints an array of any type that I send to it. I tried

```
public static <T> void printArr(T[] a)
{
    int length = a.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }       
}
```

But when I try to use an array of ints it gives me an error saying "change method 'printArr(T[]) ' to 'printArr(int[])'. It works when its a normal method. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Generics do not work with primitive types.

Comment: Generic type (in your case `<T>`) can only represent classes like `Object`, `String`, and so on, not primitives like `int`, `long`...

Comment: By the way, generics is unnecessary here. It would be the same to just declare your method `public static void printArr(Object[] a)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the primitive type `int` but here, an array of `Object`s is expected so you must use the wrapper `Integer` :

```
print(new Integer[] { 1,2,3,4 });
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java's generics, [a generic type parameter must stand for an actual object type and not a primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#instantiate).  Therefore, you can't pass an `int[]` (or any other array of a primitive type) to a method expecting a generic array.

You can create an array of the wrapper type `Integer[]` (or copy an existing `int[]` to an `Integer[]`) and pass that in to `printArr`, or you can overload `printArr` to accept an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty certain that you can't use ints because any method that uses generics must be able to be cast to an Object, which int is not (it's a primitive).  If you were to provide an array of Integers I believe it would work just fine.

[Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how the equivalent function `Arrays.toString()`([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-)) is implemented. It's one function that will take an `Object[]` for example an `Integer[]`, and one for each kind of primitive-array like `int[]`. Here's the code for the `Object[]` and the `int[]` version:

#### Object[]:

```
public static String toString(Object[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";

    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(String.valueOf(a[i]));
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

#### int[]:

```
public static String toString(int[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(a[i]);
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

There's a lot to learn from this code. For example it's not using Generics in any way.

If you actually wanted to make a method that could take any array it would probably have to take an `Object`, which you could then check the class of, and invoke the appropriate `Arrays.toString()`(or generate a string manually). Probably not a good idea, however. We have overloading for a reason.

Edit:
Just for fun, here is such a method that will take any array. Actually, any Object at all.

```
public static void printAny(Object arr) {
    Class<?> cl = arr.getClass();
    if (cl.isArray()) {
        Class<?> type = cl.getComponentType();
        if (!type.isPrimitive()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[]) arr));
        } else {
            switch (type.toString()) {
                case "int":
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString((int[]) arr));
                    break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```