# is there comfortable array without autoboxing

Tags: java, arrays, primitive, autoboxing

I can't find a comfortable array, which does not use autoboxing. I need to take a very careful look at the memory-size and want to use primitive structures like `int` instead of their object-equivalent like `Integer`.

Using `int[]`, is very un-comfortable in matters of fixed size / positions. But I cannot afford using something like `LinkedList` and `ListArray` because they can only be used with `Integer` instead of `int`.

So i would like to ask, if there is any comfortable array, which can use primitive data-structures, like `int`, instead of `Objects`.

Comment: `ArrayList` instead of `ListArray`?

Comment: Also, I think this is really a Java [limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types).

Comment: The google keywords you're looking for are "primitive type collections".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly with Java collections, but there are a few external libraries implementing collections of primitive types.

For instance, GNU Trove has a [`TIntArrayList`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TIntArrayList.html) and Apache Commons Primitives has a [`ArrayIntList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-primitives/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/primitives/ArrayIntList.html). Both will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, Java does not provide `ArrayList` of `int`s by default. `ArrayList` can only contain `Object` subclasses and primitives don't inherit `Object`.

However, you could write your own implementation of `List` that operates on `int`s or - preferably - use something like [TIntArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TIntArrayList.html).