# Java generic unexpected token

Tags: java, class, generics

I have a generic class "Property" that I want to put in a HashMap, but I get an `"Unexpected token: >"` error.
I'm using Processing 2.2.1.

```
class MouseEvent extends Event{
  HashMap<String, Property> Args;
  MouseEvent(String type){
    Args = new HashMap<String, Property>();
    Args.put("mouseX", new Property<int>(mouseX)); //throws unexpected token
    Args.put("mouseY", new Property<int>(mouseY));
    Args.put("Button", new Property<int>(mouseButton));
    Args.put("Type", new Property<String>(type));
  }
}


class Property<T>{
  private T val;
  Poperty(T v){
    val = v;
  }
  void Set(T v){
    val = v;
  }
  T Get(){
    return val;
  }
}
```

What am I misunderstanding here? :/

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use primitive data types like `int` as the generic type. You have to use the corresponding Object i.e `Integer`.

Change your code to

```
Args.put("mouseX", new Property<Integer>(mouseX));
```

Also on side note follow java naming conventions. Variable/method names should be in camel case

```
HashMap<String, Property> args;
args = new HashMap<String, Property>();
//...
```

Comment: I tried that before posting this thread and got a similar error..but it is working now. I'm not sure what else has changed.