# Assigning Scala's Map that has Any type to Java variable

Tags: java, scala

I have a Scala variable of type Map[String, Any].

```
object Maps
{
  var no_string: Map[String, Any] = Map(
  ...
```

I also have a Scala method that uses this type as a parameter.

```
def generateContext(rep: Map[String, Any], m: Int, k: Int, q: Int) : Array[Byte]
```

In Java, I can invoke the method using the type as follows.

```
wifi.generateContext(Maps.no_string(), m, k, q);
```

Then, how can I store the `Maps.no_string()` into Java variable? In other words, what type do I need to use for storing them?

```
Map(???)[String, Any(???)] x = Maps.no_string();
```

[image]

Using IntelliJ, I have too many options, I just chose `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, but I don't know how to setup the `Any`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "convert" it to `Map[String, AnyRef]`, which corresponds to `scala.collection.immutable.Map<String, Object>`:

```
scala> val a: Map[String, Any] = Map("a" -> 1)
a: Map[String,Any] = Map(a -> 1)

scala> val b: Map[String, AnyRef] = a.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]]
b: Map[String,AnyRef] = Map(a -> 1)

scala> b("a") //no ClassCastException as there is nothing to cast
res7: AnyRef = 1
```

Boxing for generic types is done automatically in Scala as Java [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types) primitive types in them, as any type `T` for JVM is always turned (erased) to the `Object`.

More than that `scala.collection.immutable.Map<String, Object>` works without any explicit convertions:

```
//Scala
class A {
  val a = Map[String, Any]("a" -> 1) //it's `Any` but fits to AnyRef/Object
}

//Java
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        scala.collection.immutable.Map<String, Object> map = a.a(); //it's AnyRef/Object and btw fits only to AnyRef if you'd try to use it from Scala
        System.out.println("Hello World!" + map.apply("a"));
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Hello World!1
```

Obviously, scala represents both `Any` (exactly formal `Any` type - not subtypes) and `AnyRef` as Java's `Object`, but not vice versa (Java's `Object` is represented as `AnyRef` only). Formal `Int` type may be represented by either `int` or `Integer` and so on.

P.S. About scala's automatical boxing for generics (for instance, `Int` inside generic will always be represented as boxed `Integer` if it's passed to the generic) - the only exception is specialized methods, but they just generate additional overloaded unboxed implementations, so the call from Java should be safe anyway (as exactly the method that takes/returns `AnyRef` will be choosed).

Answer (score 0):

`Any` does not exist in Java; it's a scala-specific type.  Java's `Map` can only have `Object` values (which correspond to scala's `AnyRef`), and not primitives, so you'll need to do a more careful conversion:

```
val m = Map[String, Any]("a" -> 1, "b" -> "two")
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val javaMap: java.util.Map[String, java.lang.Object] = 
  m.mapValues {
    case x: AnyRef => x: java.lang.Object
    case x: Int => Integer.valueOf(x)
    // etc for other primatives...
  }.asJava
```