# Error when changing method argument from String to int

Tags: java, generics

I used this example code:
https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/DirectedGraphDemo to create a digraph. In this example, the Digraph is created with vertices that are `Strings`. I need vertices to be points, which I designate with an iD in my code (iDs are going from 0 to 3 so these are `int`). So I modified the example to do this:

```
public class DirectedGraphDemo {
    public static void graph(int ... iD) {
        // constructs a directed graph with the specified vertices and edges
        DirectedGraph<int, DefaultEdge> directedGraph =
            new DefaultDirectedGraph<int, DefaultEdge>
            (DefaultEdge.class);
        directedGraph.addVertex(0);
        directedGraph.addVertex(1);
        directedGraph.addVertex(2);
        directedGraph.addVertex(3);

        directedGraph.addEdge(0,1);
        directedGraph.addEdge(1,2);
        directedGraph.addEdge(2,3);

        // computes all the strongly connected components of the directed graph
        StrongConnectivityInspector sci =
            new StrongConnectivityInspector(directedGraph);
        List stronglyConnectedSubgraphs = sci.stronglyConnectedSubgraphs();

        // prints the strongly connected components
        System.out.println("Strongly connected components:");
        for (int i = 0; i < stronglyConnectedSubgraphs.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(stronglyConnectedSubgraphs.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Prints the shortest path from vertex 0 to vertex 3. This certainly
        // exists for our particular directed graph.
        System.out.println("Shortest path from 0 to 3:");
        List path =
            DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween(directedGraph, 0, 3);
        System.out.println(path + "\n");

    }
}
```

However, I get the error "unexpected token int" at the line:

```
DirectedGraph<int, DefaultEdge> directedGraph =
```

I changed the arguments of the method to `int` so why am I getting this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types)

Comment: Might be a duplicate but I had no idea that my problem could be formulated like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the primitive types as generics, so change it to `Integer`. Autoboxing will work so you won't have to change everything else to `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java's generics, a primitive type such as `int` is not allowed as a type parameter.  As a substitute, you can use Java's wrapper types for primitive types.  Here you can use `Integer` instead of `int`.

```
DirectedGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = // ,...
```

Java's boxing/unboxing features will handle the conversion from `int` to `Integer` and back implicitly.