# Generic swap method for int array

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a simple generic method that swaps two entries in an array but when I call the method it gives the the following error. What am I missing? I'm sure it's an easy fix I just can't see it.

[image]

Sorting.java

```
package testing;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class Sorting {

    public static <T> void swap(T[] array, int left, int right){
        T temp = array[right];
        array[right] = array[left];
        array[left] = temp;
    }
}
```

SortTest.java

```
package testing;

import static testing.Sorting.*;

public class SortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] nums = {5, 12, 3, 7, 2};
        swap(nums, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass primitives as a generic type.

Comment: `Sorting.swap(nums, 0 ,1);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in Java to make a generic method that allows primitives to be accepted.  You cannot pass an `int[]` to a method that expects a `T[]`, nor can you make any method generic over different kinds of primitives.  You could use a boxed array like `Integer[]`, or you could custom-write an overload that accepted an `int[]`.

You also have the problem that you *would* need to write `Sorting.swap(nums, 0, 1)` instead of just `swap(nums, 0, 1)`, or you would need to write `import static testing.Sorting.swap;` as an import statement.

Comment: @wero added that in too.

Comment: It is possible to make a method that accepted all types of arrays (primitive arrays and reference arrays), by taking type `Object`, and it would be able to operate on the array without caring about the element type by using reflection. However, this wouldn't be a generic method, nor would it be type-safe.

Answer (score 2):

The method signature is a generic `Object[]` which you can't assign an `int[]`

```
int[] nums = {1};
Object[] o = nums; // doesn't compile
```

And hence the method won't allow it. 
 You can use `Integer[]` instead.

```
Integer[] nums = {5, 12, 3, 7, 2};
```

Note that auto-boxing doesn't work with arrays, when generics methods allow primitives, there is auto-boxing behind the scenes.

Generics and primitives types don't play well together. (Things might get better in Java 10)

Answer (score 0):

1. swap method is a static one, though one that is specific to a class. In order to call it you need the `className.method` or `instanceOfClass.method` (this will be translated at compile time in `class.method`)
2. Generic cannot be applied to primitives: see [Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types)