# Constrain the generic type parameter on an open generic type definition to only primitives/value types

Tags: java

I'd like to constrain the generic type parameter `T` in the open type defined below to only be a value type, i.e. a primitive such as `int` or `double` and not the wrappers/reference types.

```
public class Size<T> {

  protected T width;
  protected T height;

  // Getters and setters and ctor
  // ...
}
```

Like in C#, I'd do something like so:

```
public class Size<T> 
  where T: struct 
{
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way to tell Java to do that?

Comment: Which one do you want: Java or C# generic constraint? The constraint technique is different for both languages.

Comment: Good question. I must add clarification. I want the Java one. Editing the question.

Comment: Is that you want Java version from provided C# code? `where T: struct` value type constraint only exist in C#, Java has something like `<? extends T>` or `<? super T>` instead (but only work for reference types, note generic type erasure). Also note that there is no struct value type in Java.

Comment: You can't paramterise generics with primitive types in Java.

Comment: I know the C# bit. I want the Java bit. I've edited my question.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's what I've been noticing. Why is that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks so very much.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 In Java we often use `public class Size<T extends Something>`. But as I mentioned before, `Something` must be reference type though.

Comment: you cannot use a primitive directly as a generic, it should be a class.
what you can do is use Number class. <T extends Number>. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Comment: @SarthakMittal It applies if OP needs to constrain with primitive wrapper classes. But if the `struct` contains something like `DateTime` or other custom value types which only C# can declare them, it requires other class type to extends with.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I understand that, just mentioning what's possible in Java. :)