# Java Stream Collectors.toList() wont compile

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Can any one explain why the below code will not compile but the second one does?

**Do not compile**

```
private void doNotCompile() {

    List<Integer> out;
    out = IntStream
            .range(1, 10)
            .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
            .map(e -> Integer.valueOf(2 * e))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(out);
}
```

Compilation errors on the *collect* line

- The method collect(Supplier, ObjIntConsumer, BiConsumer) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector>)
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector> to Supplier

**Compiles**

```
private void compiles() {
    List<Integer> in;

    in = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    List<Integer> out;
    out = in.stream()
            .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
            .map(e -> 2 * e)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(out);
}
```

Comment: Next time, add the error message instead of just stating it won't compile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`IntStream` doesn't have a `collect` method that accepts a `Collector`. If you want a `List<Integer>`, you have to box the `IntStream` into a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
out = IntStream
        .range(1, 10)
        .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
        .map(e -> 2 * e)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

An alternative to `.map().boxed()` is `mapToObj()`:

```
out = IntStream
        .range(1, 10)
        .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
        .mapToObj(e -> 2 * e)
        .collect(Collectors.toList ());
```

or you can use the `IntStream` `collect` method:

```
out = IntStream
        .range(1, 10)
        .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
        .map(e -> 2 * e)
        .collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

Comment: "IntStream doesn't have a collect method that accepts a Collector" ... specifically because there is no such thing as a `List<int>`

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are operating over a stream of primitive integers. Primitive integers can't go into a `List`, [basically because generics in Java are less than ideal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types). Java language designers are [working on potentially fixing this](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218).

In the meantime, to solve this you need to box these primitive ints into an [`Integer` wrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) first. See [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46827953/1898563) for a code sample.

In the second example, you're already iterating over `Integer`s so *It Just Works*™.

---

> I thought I was boxing those int to Integers when I did
>   Integer.valueOf in the mapper

The [`map` function of `IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) takes a [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html) which is a functional interface that takes a primitive int and returns a primitive int.

The `Integer` you get from `valueOf` is unboxed to match the functional interface.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought I was boxing those int to Integers when I did Integer.valueOf in the mapper

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: I get it now, it also works if I use maptoObj instead of map

Answer (score 1):

The `collect` method of `IntStream` is different in the non-compilable case.

```
public <R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier, ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

Therefore it does not accept the parameter you supplied to `collect`

You could get around this by casting `List<Integer>` to the `IntStream`