# Is there a way to check what variable type is used using generics?

Tags: java, variables, generics

Take for example this pseudocode:

```
public static<T> int findNumber(T xNumber, double a, int b){
    if (xNumber == int) {
        // do something... return some number...
    } else {
        return null; 
    }
```

Is there a way to express this in real functioning Java code?

Comment: instanceof  ... o.getClass() == Integer.getClass() .. just so you understand: int is a primitive, so that won't work.

Comment: if you need to check type of generic object, means it something wrong with our design.

Comment: Agreed with @user902383. If you need more control on your `T` generic definition, consider putting restriction such `<T extends ...>` in your method definition

Comment: You likely don't need generics at all, replace T with `Number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot express this specific case using Java code.

You may find [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types) about the reasons.

However, if you wish to use generics with integers, the [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) Java class supports genericity. It also implements every basic operations (+ - * / %) used by native int. In your example, you may use:

```
if (xNumber instanceof Integer)
```

of even

```
if (xNumber.getClass() == Integer.getClass())
```

as suggested by @Stultuske in the comments.

---

EDIT: The commentaries about the design of your class are also very true. You may want to re-design your code, so you won't have to check for the type of your generic object (especially since you're checking for a single class type).

Comment: `Integer.class` (copy error); and `of` = Dutch for `or` ;)

Comment: ... I didn't get it.

Comment: `aNumber.getClass() == Integer.class`

Comment: 1 month later, I understood, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The class [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) leads an almost hidden existence but is quite useful.

```
public static <T extends Number> int findNumber(...)
    ... xNumber.intValue() // longValue(), doubleValue()
    if (xNumber instanceof Integer) ...
```

Because of type erasure more is not feasible.