# How do i cast my ArrayList with integers into a normal Array of integers?

Tags: java, arrays

```
    Temp = ReadLeaderboard();
    int[] TrueLeaderboards = Temp.toArray(new int[Temp.size()]);
```

The ArrayList Temp reads the data correctly, but when i try cast it and store into a normal Array of integers it won't allow it?

Comment: You should post a more complete example and give the exact error you are facing.

Answer (score 4):

You could use streams to accomplish this.

```
List<Integer> integers = magicSupplier();  // however it is that you get the list
int[] ints = integers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Otherwise, you need to unbox the `Integer` to `int`, as the object `Integer` is not a primitive `int`. The fact that you need to unbox this is why your code doesn't work: you are basically providing an `int[]` to be populated by `Integer`.

Also, Java naming conventions state that you should name variables (unless they are constants) with lowercase names, i.e. your `Temp` variable should be called `temp`. Only objects should be capitalised like `Temp`.

Comment: Thankyou that worked :)

Comment: With `Integer::valueOf` you're implicitly boxing the `Integer` to `int` so it can be passed to `valueOf`, which returns an `Integer`, then it's implicitly unboxed back to `int`.  Just use `Integer::intValue`.

Comment: You're right, changed.

Answer (score 2):

It won't allow you to send an `int[]` into the [`toArray` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-), because that method accepts an array of a type parameter, which must be a reference type, not a primitive type such as `int`.

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

You can use [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-int:A-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) to copy the elements into an array you've created.  That method takes an `IntUnaryOperator` that supplies an index and expects the value.

```
int[] arr = new int[temp.size()];
Arrays.setAll(arr, index -> temp.get(index));
```

There are overloads of `Arrays.setAll` for setting `long[]`, `double[]`, and `T[]` arrays, as well as corresponding `parallelSetAll` methods that are parallel versions of each method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a primitive array as a generic parameter. See [Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types) and use a [primitive wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) instead:

```
Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```