# How could I specify a type that match both String and long?

Tags: java, types

The situation is I have a function, and it calls `Arrays.sort` to sort given array. As `Arrays.sort` can sort both String and long, I want to use one single signature instead of two `String[] array` and `long[] array`.

I've tried something like `Comparable[]`, it won't match `long[]`. I've also tried change `long` to `Long`. But the process of boxing and unboxing is significantly slowing down the sorting.

So I am wondering if there is a type I can specify that matches both of them? Or generally match all supported types of `Arrays.sort`?

Comment: The only thing which comes to mind would be to just store your long numbers as `String`.  But the problem there is that numbers and text numbers don't sort the same way.  Maybe you can add information to your question which explains why you need to do this.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a way to do this--in fact, the JDK itself has a separate overload for each primitive array type for `Arrays.sort`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **no**, you can't.

`Comparable` is an interface and part of the object/class-system. A primitive, such as `long`, is not part of that system, only its boxed variant `Long`.

Unfortunately, you even can not solve this using generics, since they can also  only be applied to classes, not to primitives (see [Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types)).

So until [Project Valhalla](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/) (value types) releases, you will need to provide hard-coded variants for all 8 primitives (`short`, `int`, `long`, `byte`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `boolean`) if you want to avoid auto-boxing, there is no way around.

The Java API must do this too. You see overloaded methods of `Arrays#sort` for all relevant primitives and one generic overload for classes. From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
sort​(byte[] a)
sort​(char[] a)
sort​(double[] a)
sort​(float[] a)
sort​(int[] a)
sort​(long[] a)
sort​(short[] a)
sort​(Object[] a)
sort​(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Comment: Just cannot believe this is how Java works... I really miss Python for now.

Comment: It's due to the nature of how generics are implemented in Java. And unfortunately it was not possible to go a different way without breaking backwards compatibility (which is an important point for Java) back then.

Comment: Yeah I understand this is a historical problem. Not Java's fault.

Comment: It may change once Valhalla is finished though :)

Comment: I learned Java many years ago and it hasn't improved even a little on this part... It is just the same as that time.

Comment: I agree for that specific part of the language. However, there were many other nice additions in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

> The situation is I have a function, and it calls `Arrays.sort` to sort
>   given array. As `Arrays.sort` can sort both `String` and `long`, I
>   want to use one single signature instead of two `String[]` array and
>   `long[]` array.

One can try *method overloading* like this.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String [] strs = {"c", "x", "a", "d"};
    long [] ints = {4L, 343660L, 99L, 0L};
    Testing t = new Testing();
    t.sortMyArray(strs);
    t.sortMyArray(ints);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs)); // [a, c, d, x]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints)); // [0, 4, 99, 343660]
}

private void sortMyArray(long[] myArray) {
    Arrays.sort(myArray);
}

private void sortMyArray(String[] myArray) {
    Arrays.sort(myArray);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I mean "two signatures".

Comment: In Java this is one method signature - and is a case of overloaded methods.

Comment: This is a method with two different signatures. Or specifically, these are two functions with the same name.

Comment: In case just two types of arrays a method like this can work, but overloading is preferred: `public void sortMyArray(String [] strs, long [] ints) { // have logic to sort any or both arrays...};` To call such a method: `sortMyArray(strs, ints);` -or-`sortMyArray(null, ints)`; -or- `sortMyArray(strs, null);` etc., it gets tedious.