# Pass reference of array of unknown type (Either Object or Primitive) to function

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a general function that takes in an array of Unknown type and flips it. It doesn't return anything and should pass a reference to the array to the function.

I've tried to use Varargs:

```java
public static <Unknown> void reverseArray(Unknown... a){
  Unknown t;
  for(int i=0;i<a.length/2;i++){
    t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
    a[a.length - i - 1] = t;
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work for primtives because java doesn't seem to pass in a reference to an array
I've tried Object[]

```java
public static void reverseArray(Object[] a){
  Object t;
  for(int i=0;i<a.length/2;i++){
    t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
    a[a.length - i - 1] = t;
  }
}
```

But when when I pass it `int[]` java says it is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

Same thing with generics:

```java
public static <Unknown> void reverseArray(Unknown[] a){
  Unknown t;
  for(int i=0;i<a.length/2;i++){
    t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
    a[a.length - i - 1] = t;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of primitives, you would need to use the class version of the primitives (`Integer` instead of `int`) if you wish to go this route I think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types have a look at this answer as it can propably help you on why you cant do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it.  You have to have a separate method for each `primitive type` you want to support.

Take a look at the `Java API` for `Arrays.toString()` to see all the methods.  Same for `copyOf` and for `sort` too, as well as others.

And even for `Generic types`, the `common` method must be something that can support all types.  The previously sited examples are some.  But you couldn't have a generic method that `added two numbers` because for a type `T`, the compiler would not know if `T` supported a particular operation.

Comment: WHAT?!? Why is Java made this way? it seems like the compiler could do this easily...

Comment: @Zyansheep Generics don't accept primitive types but use autoboxing to get the wrapper class. This doesn't work with Arrays but you can look into autoboxing, maybe you find a solution to your problem.