# How come the .getClass().getName() method works with type int?

Tags: java

I have been told that primitive types such as `int` do not have methods to them. How is it that *`.getClass().getName()`* works when used on a variable of type `int` and returns the wrapper class "`Integer`"? Is this an example of auto boxing?

Important: This only seems to work for me when the `int` variable is passed into a generic class. Then a method in the generic class is invoked from the main method.

I am using this generic class:

```java
public class gen< T > {

    private T thing;

    public gen(T thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }

    public String varType() {
        return thing.getClass().getName();
    }
}

public class Driver() {
    int i = 5;
    gen g = new gen(i);
    System.out.println(g.getType());
}
```

> The output is : java.lang.Integer

Could someone please explain the inner workings of this process?

Something like this will not work:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int i = 5;
    i.getClass().getName();
}
```

Comment: Your generic type here is Integer, not int. The int is boxed to an Integer when you use it as a generic. Primitive types cannot be used as generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type parameters, e.g. `T`, cannot be *primitives*. For primitive types, you use the corresponding wrapper class. Said more specifically, `T` cannot be `int`.

In your case, the compiler **auto-boxed** the `int` value to an `Integer` for you in the `new gen(i)` call.

See: [Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2721546/5221149)

---

*Note 1:* `gen` and `new gen` are *raw generics*, since you omitted the type parameter. Do not use raw generics. Besides, what's the point if you ignore them anyway?

*Note 2:* Java naming convension is for class names to start with uppercase letter, so class should be named `Gen`, not `gen`.