# Map with long as key in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, maps, long-integer

My profiler state I spend an important part of the time wrapping `long` into `Long` which I want to avoid. I currently do it because I use `Map<Long, V>`. Is there an usual way to create a Map whose keys are `long` ?

I know it won't be a `Map<long, V>` because the type system does not allow it, but that does not mean that a map from `long` to `V` can't exists. Actually, it would be quite easy to do, since I would just need to copy the code of `HashMap<K,V>`, replace `K` by `long`, and do all changes required by the type system (E.g. iteration over key would not be an `Iterator<K>` anymore)

My question is does such a library already exists, or should I do it myself ?

The context is that my profiler state that, when doing batch processing, a third of the time is spent transforming `long` into `Long`, and there is really no reason to accept to pay this price for the type system

Comment: try Long The wrapper class for primitive long

Comment: My point is that wrapping takes time and is uselessly costly here according to the profiler. That's why I want to avoid it in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/ is a class of library doing exactly what I was asking for here

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported as [generics does not support primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types). You cannot create a class with primitive types as well (like `HashMap<int,V>`).

Maybe the [JEP 218 - Generics over Primitive Types](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218) will look to solve this in the future.

**Suggestions:**

1. Can you change the rest of the code to use a `Long` in the first place?
2. The Long class caches values from -127 to 128 ([code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/f92ab6dbbff8/src/share/classes/java/lang/Long.java#l784)). Explore if you could have a similar internal cache for a bigger range.