# Android : Translate in Java the Kotlin ViewModel backing field encapsulation technique

Tags: android, kotlin, encapsulation, android-viewmodel, backing-field

In an Android App written in Kotlin, LiveData properties in the ViewMoel can be encapsulated using the backing field technique like so :

```
private val _score = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val score: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _score
```

How can I translate this in Java to obtain the same level of encapsulation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, class only have field and function, so you can create a private field with a getter like this to achieve the result.

```
private final MutableLiveData<Int> score = new MutableLiveData<>();

public final LiveData<Int> getScore(){
    return score;
}
```

Comment: Looks good. I did not realized that MutableLiveData<Int>could be casted in LiveData<Int>  What about a set method?     public void setScore(Int){score.setValue(s);}  Is this setScore compliant with encapsulation rules?

Comment: You can use the set method like that. Usually, I do not create a setter for live data field. Just name it directly with the action you want to do. For example: `resetScore()`, `increaseScore()`, ... and inside these method, call `score.setValue()` or `score.postValue()` to update the live data value.

Comment: Makes sens. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

this is a normal getter method and this is the converted **java** code

```
private final MutableLiveData<Integer> _score = new MutableLiveData<Integer>();

@NotNull
public final LiveData<Integer> getScore() {
    return this._score;
}
```

this is the steps to get the **java** code form **kotlin**

in android studio

> tools -> kotlin -> show kotlin byte code -> Decompile

Comment: There is no Generic type Int any more. In fact, decomile show a @Metadata. It seems too complicated to use this solution in a pure Java app. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have edited the answer , you can use `Integer`as a generic type

Comment: "this" can be omitted so you have basically the same solution as Kim Ninh below. Thanks.

Comment: yes , if you are on the same context, but generics doesn't works with primitive types like `int` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types