# Why arrays can be used in the generic in JAVA？

Tags: java, generics

`int` is primitive type in java. Why is `int[]` usable as a generic type?

I can write code like this and compile it.

```
List<int[]> test = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Because `int[]` is a reference type. `new int[0] instanceof Object` is true.

Comment: What is the type of `int[]`? Object?

Comment: The type of `int[]` object is `int[]`.

Comment: When you write `int[]`, you're not indicating an `int` array precisely; you're indicating an array of `int`.  The `int` designation just  states the type of the elements stored in the array, not the type of the array itself.

Comment: `int[]` has many properties, such as length. Where is it defined?

Comment: @HongYi: In the JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1

Answer (score 3):

Indeed **int** is a primitive however an array of integers, **int[]**, isn't.

Java [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) define an array as,

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of
> a single type.

As you can see an array is an object with class hierarchy as following,

```
java.lang.Object
    java.util.Arrays
```

So arrays in java are basically objects of type **[java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)**. The same class also provides all the good operations you can perform on Arrays.

Back to your question, you're right, Java doesn't allow passing primitives as type parameter when you're using generics.

You cannot do this,

```
List<int> test = new ArrayList<int>();
```

However you can do generics with Integer class just fine,

```
List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

The reasons for not allowing primitives are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types) on stackoverflow.

One might think, Java does support autoboxing so why not simply autobox primitives to their equivalent classes. Well that is a design choice. Primitives are efficient and cost less memory. Designers probably rightly decided to not assume autoboxing would serve equivalent efficiency.

Comment: A more fitting cite would be the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-10.html): "*In the Java programming language, arrays are objects ...*"

Comment: @Turing85 yes, thanks.

Comment: *"Arrays in java are basically objects of type java.util.Arrays"* -- I don't think that is correct.  `Arrays` is mostly a utility class containing `static` methods that can be used to operate on arrays.  It is not the basis for an array type.  For example, you don't say `myArray.sort()`, you say `Arrays.sort(myArray)`.