# remove() on List created by Arrays.asList() throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

I have a collection `c1<MyClass>` and an array `a<MyClass>`.  I am trying to convert the array to a collection `c2` and do `c1.removeAll(c2)`, But this throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.  I found that the `asList()` of Arrays class returns `Arrays.ArrayList` class and the this class inherits the `removeAll()` from `AbstractList()` whose implementation throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
    Myclass la[] = getMyClass();
    Collection c = Arrays.asList(la);
    c.removeAll(thisAllreadyExistingMyClass);
```

Is there any way to remove the elements? please help

Comment: related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-i-get-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-from-the-list

Answer (score 192, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a `List` wrapper around an array. This wrapper has a fixed size and is directly backed by the array, and as such calls to `set` will modify the array, and any other method that modifies the list will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

To fix this, you have to create a new modifiable list by copying the wrapper list's contents. This is easy to do by using the `ArrayList` constructor that takes a `Collection`:

```
Collection c = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(la));
```

Comment: I was looking at the source code for `java.util.Arrays` `asList()` method, and it seems to return an `ArrayList`. However, when I do a `System.out.println(list.getClass());`, I get `class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`. So it uses the inner `ArrayList` class, which doesn't have a `add` or `remove` method. I'm just wondering what's  the point of having an inner `ArrayList` class instead of using the `java.util.ArrayList` one and why not have an `add()` and `remove()` method?

Comment: Correction to my above comment: it does have an `add` and `remove` method

Comment: @Abdul Because there is no such thing as a fixed size `java.util.ArrayList`. You want an implementation of `List` that throws an exception if you do something illegal with it (such as adding or removing), and `ArrayList` does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: @Abdul `Arrays.asList` just creates a wrapper `List`. But it's still a `java.util.List`, so it must have those methods. But they cannot be applied because that would lead to creating a new array with different size. Which can't be done because the modifications you can still do can be done both through the returned List and the original array. This won't be possible if the returned List could change so that it would basically throw away the original array reference.

Answer (score 16):

Yup, the `Arrays.asList(..)` is collection that can't be expanded or shrunk (because it is backed by the original array, and it can't be resized).

If you want to remove elements either create a `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(..)` or remove elements directly from the array (that will be less efficient and harder to write)

Comment: +1 This answer is the only correct one: Arrays.asList() returns an *unmodifiable* list - that's what's throwing the exception. It's nothing to do with being "backed by an array" etc... *all* ArrayLists are backed by arrays - big deal.

Comment: @Bohemian Perhaps you should re-read my answer, then, because I think I meet your requirements.

Comment: @Bohemian Did you really read, or did you stop at the first sentence? In fact, the doc for `asList` even states "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array". It's hardly irrelevant, it's _the exact wording of the official documentation_.

Comment: But if you'd read further into the docs, you'd realize that it is not actually unmodifiable...  "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)"  -1, Etienne is quite right.

Comment: @Steven Yes, that's why it says "fixed size" rather than "unmodifiable" or "read only". Actually, I'll go edit my answer right now to reflect that.

Comment: It is not implemented *because* it would be impossible to do so without violating the "fixed size" constraint.  How could you implement removeAll without violating that?  If the List were of variable size, I am quite sure that the wrapper would implement it.

Comment: @Bohemian That's not rephrasing, that's a completely different meaning. And my answer is not "completely wrong", it's at worst badly worded. Exceptions are thrown because the collection has a fixed size; overriding the methods is just the technique used to enforce that contract.

Comment: OK, let me re-phrase. Your explanation of why the exception is thrown is wrong. The `UnsupportedException` is thrown *not* because "This wrapper has a fixed size" or any other similar reason. It is thrown because the list returned from Arrays.asList extends AbstractList and doesn't override the modifier methods, which by default throw the exception - nothing to do with the backing array. Your solution however is correct.

Comment: @Bohemian, The returned collections is infact 'modifiable' because it is possible to call the 'set' method.

Comment: If you're going to pick nits like that, you might as well say vapid things like "it throws UnsupportedOperationException because there is a throw UnsupportedOperationException statement in the code".  Consumers of an API don't care which AbstractBlah superclass is throwing an exception, they care what the contracts and expectations of the class they use are.  In JVM v+1, it is entirely possible the class library changes where the exception is thrown - but the contract will not change.

Comment: @Bohemian Of course it's thrown because a method is overriden: that's how it's done in Java. The thing is, _why_ was the method overriden to throw an exception instead of defaulting to `ArrayList`'s behavior? Because it has a fixed size. I'm talking about design, you're talking about implementation details.

Comment: @Steven Schlansker fixed the wording. (removed "unmodifiable")

Comment: I was looking at the source code for `java.util.Arrays` `asList()` method, and it seems to return an `ArrayList`. However, when I do a `System.out.println(list.getClass());`, I get `class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`. So it uses the inner `ArrayList` class, which doesn't have a `add` or `remove` method. I'm just wondering what's  the point of having an inner `ArrayList` class instead of using the `java.util.ArrayList` one and why not have an `add()` and `remove()` method?

Comment: Correction to my above comment: it does have an `add` and `remove` method

Answer (score 8):

That is the way `Array.asList()` works, because it is directly backed by the array.
To get a fully modifiable list, you would have to clone the collection into a collection created by yourself.

```
Collection c = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(la))
```

Comment: The list is modifiable but only through set(). the returned collection is fixed-size.

Comment: I never actually said it was unmodifiable. Just that to get a (fully) modifiable list you would have to use an `ArrayList`. The difference perhaps wasn't too clear though. :-) Whether the list is modifiable or not is a question of definition, it is "semi-modifiable" but not fully modifiable in my view.