# Why does List.remove(int) throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: java

I am trying to remove elements from a `List` and getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
    public <T extends Object> void findDuplicates(
        String title, Multimap<T, ChunkId> map) {
        for (T key : map.keySet()) {
            Collection<ChunkId> ids = map.get(key);
            List<ChunkId> idList = (Arrays.asList(ids.toArray(new ChunkId[0])));
            removeUsedIds(idList);
            Collections.sort(idList);
//...
        }
    }

    private void removeUsedIds(List<ChunkId> idList) {
        // decrement counter to avoid indexing changed parts of list
        for (int i = idList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (usedIdSet.contains(idList.get(i))) {
                idList.remove(i);   // **** Exception thrown here
            }
        }
    }
```

and I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at org.xmlcml.svg2xml.analyzer.PDFIndex.removeUsedIds(PDFIndex.java:104)
    at org.xmlcml.svg2xml.analyzer.PDFIndex.findDuplicates(PDFIndex.java:87)
    at org.xmlcml.svg2xml.analyzer.PDFIndex.findDuplicatesInIndexes(PDFIndex.java:129)
    at org.xmlcml.svg2xml.analyzer.PDFAnalyzer.analyzePDF(PDFAnalyzer.java:188)
    at org.xmlcml.svg2xml.analyzer.PDFAnalyzer.analyzePDFFile(PDFAnalyzer.java:115)
    at org.xmlcml.svg2xml.analyzer.PDFAnalyzer.main(PDFAnalyzer.java:398)
```

NOTE: This is flagged as a duplicate of [remove() on List created by Arrays.asList() throws UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885573/remove-on-list-created-by-arrays-aslist-throws-unsupportedexception) but it's significantly different. That poster *knew* what the problem was and wanted an explanation; I *did not know what the problem was* and couldn't find it on SO by posting the current question. Java 6 docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) gives no hint of the problem (its signature throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`). The previous question also used `removeAll()` while this question referred to `remove(int)` so lexical searching is less precise.

I therefore asked on SO and got rapid and useful answers. Because I phrased the title exactly (unlike the previous question) it should be easy for others to find this answer. In less than a day it already has nearly as many votes as the previous question in a year (and 100+ views), suggesting that it will be significantly more useful.  Since this question is now linked to the previous one I think it adds to the general usefulness without polluting SO. (The current answers are short and don't unnecessarily repeat information.)

I have edited the question to remove extraneous code. If this question had been available when I encountered the problem it would have saved me an hour!

Comment: which line does it happen?

Comment: You need to add one more piece of information: what kind of list did you previously instantiate?

Comment: Marked as a dupe because the `idList` you're passing into the `removeUsedIds()` method is created using the `Arrays.asList()` method, which returns a List wrapper around the array, which does not support modification.

Comment: The problem arose for me because the creation of the list was considerably removed from its modification. I tried to search SO for previous answers and didn't find them. [The previous question mentioned `UnsupportedException`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You're using it on a `List` implementation returned by `Arrays.asList()`, which returns a fixed-length collection, therefore a `remove` is unsupported.

Answer (score 52):

[`Arrays#asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) creates an *unmodifiable list*:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

Try to do:

```
List<ChunkId> idList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(ids.toArray(new ChunkId[0])));
```

Instead of:

```
List<ChunkId> idList = (Arrays.asList(ids.toArray(new ChunkId[0])));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-do-i-get-an-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-an-element-f

Comment: yes seems it should be `new LinkedList<>` not `new ArrayList` (from @thanga link)

Answer (score 18):

This is because `Arrays.asList()` creates wrapper list over array. Exactly as array's length cannot be changed the length of this list cannot be changed too.

If you want to create "real" list filled with elements of your array do the following:

`new ArrayList<ChunkId>(Arrays.asList(array))`