# How to find and remove an element from Scala ListBuffer?

Tags: java, scala, collections, iterator

The following code throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` with Scala 2.12.7 and Java 11.0.1.

```
listBuffer
.iterator
.dropWhile(_ != u)
.asJava
.remove()
```

Why? `ListBuffer` is mutable, and using an `Iterator` to remove elements while traversing should be valid. The `ListBuffer` contains `Int`.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException was thrown.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.remove(Wrappers.scala:31)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.remove(Wrappers.scala:26)
    at week4.UndirectedGraph.$anonfun$removeVertex$2(UndirectedGraph.scala:52)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcVI$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcVI$sp.java:12)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder.foreach$(TraversableForwarder.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:43)
    at week4.UndirectedGraph.$anonfun$removeVertex$1(UndirectedGraph.scala:50)
```

**Edit:**
Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28112309/839733) question, since the problem with that is trying to structurally modify the list returned by `Arrays.asList`. I shouldn't have to state the obvious, if not for the people who don't know the answer, but are usually the first to try to close a question as duplicate.

Comment: Where's the stacktrace? What's `listBuffer`'s content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnsupportedOperationException when using iterator.remove()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112309/unsupportedoperationexception-when-using-iterator-remove)

Comment: @erip where’s array here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1f76b24112eb8aa0ac25065b7939cde8ee34b61e/src/library/scala/collection/convert/Wrappers.scala#L40) code throwing the error:

```
 case class IteratorWrapper[A](underlying: Iterator[A]) extends ju.Iterator[A] with ju.Enumeration[A] {
    def hasNext = underlying.hasNext
    def next() = underlying.next()
    def hasMoreElements = underlying.hasNext
    def nextElement() = underlying.next()
    override def remove() = throw new UnsupportedOperationException
  }
```

Note that it doesn't care whether the underlying collection is mutable or not.

I think this implementation makes sense. Scala iterators do not support `remove()` by design; their conversion to Java should also yield iterators that behave the same way.

Comment: “Iterators do not support `remove` by design” - do you’ve a reference for this? I’m not seeing any such statement in the [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, 1) There is no mention of `remove` in the [Scaladocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/Iterator.html). 2) The [Iterator trait](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2787b47396013a44072fa7321482103b66fbccd3/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L348) does not define `remove`.

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a solution, in case you only need to remove elements based on object equality, just like in your example code:

Use `-=` method of the `ListBuffer`. This removes all occurences of the element from `ListBuffer`, without creating a copy of the structure.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val u = 999
    val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Int]
    listBuffer ++= Seq(1, 7, 3, 8, 0, 3, 6, 7, 999, 5, 7, 8, 999, 1, 5, 999)
    println(listBuffer)
    listBuffer -= u
    println(listBuffer)
  }
```

If you used `filter` method, than you can use a predicate, but a copy of the `ListBuffer` would be created:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val u = 999
    var listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Int]
    listBuffer ++= Seq(1, 7, 3, 8, 0, 3, 6, 7, 999, 5, 7, 8, 999, 1, 5, 999)
    println(listBuffer)
    listBuffer = listBuffer.filter(_ != u)
    println(listBuffer)
  }
```

Comment: `-=` uses object equality to find and delete the element, not a predicate