# ArrayList retainAll confusing me

Tags: java

I am trying to work with intersections in java. If I have the following, i just want an arraylist with nothing in it because the intersection gives me zero.

```
List<String> coll1 = Arrays.asList(["A"]);
List<String> coll2 = Arrays.asList(["B","C"]);

coll1.retainAll(coll2);
```

However retainAll throws this exception :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.retainAll(AbstractCollection.java:410)
```

If I convert the lists to sets, then I get a set which is empty if I call retainAll :

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(coll1);
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(coll2);

set1.retainAll(set2); //gives me an empty set, which is good!
```

Why does ArrayList have a problem with empty intersections?

Comment: How do you create `List<String>`?

Comment: If it's with `Arrays.asList()` that `List` is immutable.

Comment: See [remove() on List created by Arrays.asList() throws UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7885573/4391450) (already flagged differently but this is a duplicate...)

Comment: Please edit the code . The code given `List<String> coll1 = {"A"}` is errorful.

Comment: When you create a [mcve], please do so accurately. `List<String> coll1 = {"A"};` is not valid Java. Everyone is asking you about that one.

Comment: Does this really work `List<String> coll1 = {"A"};` ? I had to use `Arrays.asList` to initialise the array

Comment: Yes, it was with Array.asList(). Sorry updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `Arrays.asList` creates an immutable list so when you call `retainAll` which tries to remove entries from the list it complains.

The solution is to create a new `ArrayList` copy of it.

```
public void test(String[] args) {
    List<String> coll1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A"));
    List<String> coll2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("B","C"));
    coll1.retainAll(coll2);
    System.out.println(coll1);
}
```

prints:

> []

Comment: It complains specifically because the `remove` operation is unsupported in an immutable list, and `retainAll` calls `remove` on the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, and explain in your answer, you are not using explicitly an ArrayList but an AbstractList. And as explain in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection))

> **Throws:**
>   *UnsupportedOperationException* - if the retainAll operation is not supported by this collection

As you do not declare explicitly an ArrayList, you are not using an ArrayList but an AbstractList that has not implemented `retainAll`, So it throws you this Exception.

Declare your List as ArrayList and it should be okay

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```