# how could I test Lists in JUnit5?

Tags: java, junit5

I got an error when I tried to test 2 ArraysLists. 
It seems the error is saying "toArray() is undefined" at my removeEndWith_at method. Could you guys give me an advice how to test these 2 ArraysList?

Thanks.

Java version: jdk-10.0.2
JUnit:5

[ArrayListIterator Class]

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListIterator {

    /**
     * @param wordsAl : list of words
     */
    public List<String> removeEndWith_at(List<String> wordsAl) {
        Iterator<String> iterator = wordsAl.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next().endsWith("at"))
                iterator.remove();
        }

        return wordsAl;
    }

}
```

[ArrayListIteratorTest Class]

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ArrayListIteratorTest {

    ArrayListIterator alIterator = new ArrayListIterator();
    List<String> actualWords = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Bat", "Orange", "Cat");

    @Test
    void testremoveEndWith_at() {
        actualWords = alIterator.removeEndWith_at(actualWords);
        List<String> expectedvalue = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Orange");
        assertArrayEquals(expectedvalue.toArray(), actualWords.toArray());
    }

}
```

Comment: What about `assertEquals(expectedvalue, actualWords);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the

> [remove() on List created by Arrays.asList() throws UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885573/remove-on-list-created-by-arrays-aslist-throws-unsupportedoperationexception)

```
Arrays.asList()
```

method just creates a wrapper around the original elements and on this wrapper are not implemented methods which changes its size.

Also look at my implementation of method `removeEndWith_at`. It is simpler than yours version

```
        /**
     * @param wordsAl : list of words
     */
    public List<String> removeEndWith_at(List<String> wordsAl) {
            wordsAl.removeIf(s -> s.endsWith("at"));
            return wordsAl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two instances of `List<String>` using Jupiter Assertion API, give [assertLinesMatch](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertLinesMatch(java.util.List,java.util.List)) a try.