# Remove few elements from a Map of String to List for a specific key

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Map. The input is coming from another class, so I can't change the format.  The value is a List in my case.
I want to remove a few elements for a particular key.
For example, below is the input map:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("1", Arrays.asList("A","V","C","M"));
    map.put("Roll", 123);
```

This "map" has been given to me and I want to remove two entries for Key = "1", i.e., `Arrays.asList("V","M")`

I tried the below code and it worked. I want to know is there any better approach than this. Note: I am trying to do it using Java 8.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("V","M") 
List<String> lst =  map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .filter(c -> c instanceof Collection)
            .map(c -> (Collection<String>)c)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        lst.removeIf(c -> list.contains(c));
```

/**
 * After that, I can add this final list to the map again..
 */

```
final output: <"1", {"A", "C"}>
                 <"Roll", 123>
```

Comment: You can simplify `map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue)` to `map.values().stream()` in your example, but I'd like to point out that if the map has more than one value with a List as value you'll end up mashing them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of stream for doing this, i prefer using `computeIfPresent` if key present in `Map` alter the value else ignore. Don't use [Arrays.asList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885573/remove-on-list-created-by-arrays-aslist-throws-unsupportedoperationexception) unless you need immutable list because it will not support `remove` operation

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("V");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("M");

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("1", list);
    map.put("Roll", 123); 

    List<String> remove = Arrays.asList("V","M");

    map.computeIfPresent("1", (k,v)->{
              if(Objects.nonNull(v) && v instanceof List) {
                  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                  List<String> result = (List<String>) v;
                  result.removeIf(i->remove.contains(i));
                  return  result;
              }
            return v;
    });

    System.out.println(map);    //{1=[A, C], Roll=123}
```

Comment: `l` as  variable name is problematic, especially if the key is `1`.

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool . This is nice and looks very neat. Yes, `computeIfPresent` is perfect for this scenario. I've not used it before.  Will try it now.

Comment: Why am I getting  'incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression' in line  "if(Objects.nonNull(v) && v instanceof List) {"
- Cannot ase <lamda parameter> to <java.util.List>

Comment: what does it says exactly? the above code works for me, i'm on jdk 11 @RoyalTiger

Comment: It's giving a compilation error:

Inconvertible Types: Cannot cast <lamda parameter> to 'java.util.List'

I am on jdk 1.8

Comment: can you please post the error and have you tried executing it? does it break? @RoyalTiger

Comment: updated post just add that annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: Sure. It's working now @Deadpool. It's my bad. It was some local settings due to which the error was coming. Also some checkstyle errors too (All these are related to my project settings). But the above code WORKS just FINE.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the entries which are not in the list, like:

```
List<String> lst =  map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .filter(c -> c instanceof Collection)
            .map(c -> (Collection<String>)c)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(c -> !list.contains(c));
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I tried this one, but I have to put it back to the map again. I think the solution given by Deadpool looks neat and clean.