# immutability of a class when an instance variable present as arraylist

Tags: java, immutability

I have a class which is immutable

Suppose I have a getter method for a member variable of type ArrayList. In that case when I get a reference to that variable, I can add or remove an element from it. In that case immutability seems to get violated.

Can anyone explain this concept in details?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892350/immutable-vs-unmodifiable-collection

Comment: See also Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java", Item 24: Make defensive copies when needed. The chapter is available online [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2)

Comment: If you class is supposed to be all-immutable, save the reference to the list _in your class_ (after copying) as an instance of `UnmodifiableList`.  No (additional) defensive copies needed, and it prevents _your_ class from modifying it, during maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed right. Immutability is violated.

To make a class immutable, you need to make sure that all of its getters return safe copies of any class whose state could otherwise change.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't provide variable of type `ArrayList`. Provide just `List` and make sure the getter does one of the next:

1. returns a copy of your list
2. or returns unmodifiable list

or both.

Comment: Returning both a copy of the list which is also unmodifiable isn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

if you create a new instance of that changed object of type X, then instance of X would be considered as immutable. It is easier to understand if you consider your ArrayList. YOu've methods to alter this list. Each altering method make a copy of this list and add/removes/updates on the new copy and return back.