# java.util.Map values() method performance

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, collections, hashmap

I have a map like this with several million entries:

```
private final Map<String, SomeItem> tops = new HashMap<>();
```

I need to get list of values, which could be done by calling  `java.util.Map values()` method.

Is `Collection` of values created every time I call `values()` method or is it pre-computed from performance perspective?

As my `Map` has several millions elements, I do not want to create new list object every time `values()` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the copied implementation of `Map.values()` in `java.util.HashMap`:

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    Collection<V> vs = values;
    if (vs == null) {
        vs = new Values();
        values = vs;
    }
    return vs;
}
```

This clearly shows that the value collection isn't created unless necessary. So, there should not be additional overhead caused by calls to `values()`

Answer (score 1):

One important point here may be: **It does not matter!**

---

But first, referring to the other answers so far: The collection that is returned there is usually "cached", in that it is lazily created, and afterwards, the same instance will be returned. For example, considering the implementation in the `HashMap` class:

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    Collection<V> vs;
    return (vs = values) == null ? (values = new Values()) : vs;
}
```

This is even specified (as part of the contract, as an implementation specification) in the [documentation of the `AbstractMap` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#values--) (which most `Map` implementations are based on) :

> The collection is created the first time this method is called, and returned in response to all subsequent calls. No synchronization is performed, so there is a slight chance that multiple calls to this method will not all return the same collection.

---

But now, one could argue that the implementation might change later. The implementation of the `HashMap` class could change, or one might switch to another `Map` implementation that does not extend `AbstractMap`, and which is implemented differently. The fact that it is *currently* implemented like this is (for itself) no guarantee that it will *always* be implemented like this.

So the more important point (and the reason why **it does not matter**) is that the `values()` method is indeed supposed to return a **collection view**. As stated in the [documentation of the `Map` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) :

> The Map interface provides three *collection views*, which allow a map's contents to be viewed as a set of keys, collection of values, or set of key-value mappings.

and specifically, the [documentation of the `Map#values()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) :

> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map. The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa.

I cannot imagine a reasonable way of implementing such a *view* that involves processing all values of the `Map`.

---

So for example, imagine the implementation in `HashMap` was like this:

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    return new Values();
}
```

Then it would return a **new** collection each time that it was called. But creating this collection does **not** involve processing the values at all.

Or to put it that way: The cost of calling this method is *independent* of the size of the map. It basically has the cost of a single object creation, regardless of whether the map contains 10 or 10000 elements.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you can see this by looking at the code. You can also code up a quick example to prove it to yourself. The code below will print true 10 times as the object identity will always be the same for values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap();
    Collection<String> lastValues = myMap.values();
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(lastValues == myMap.values());
        lastValues = myMap.values();
    }
}
```

The following code will print true the first time and then false the next 9 times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap();
    Collection<String> lastValues = myMap.values();
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(lastValues == myMap.values());
        lastValues = myMap.values();
        myMap = new HashMap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion after reading this thread, if the Map tops declared contents are not changed - you could use google guava ImmutableMap object. For more info- [UnmodifiableMap (Java Collections) vs ImmutableMap (Google)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636575/unmodifiablemap-java-collections-vs-immutablemap-google)