# Difference between map and ImmutableMap

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, guava

I work in payment gateway company and while analyzing the code I came across
ImmuatbleMap objects. I want to know all the details about. What is it?
What are its advantages over the map? Does core java has its support for ImmuatbleMap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is meant by immutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable)

Comment: Have you read this https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained ? I think that your question is too broad for been treated here.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892350/immutable-vs-unmodifiable-collection

Comment: The main difference between `Map` and `ImmutableMap` is that the former is an interface, of which the latter is a concrete implementation.

Comment: @AndyTurner Actually `ImmutableMap` is an abstract class with additional contract (immutability guarantees), concrete implementations are hidden.

Comment: @Xaerxess OK, concrete-ish :) The point is that it implements the interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ImmutableMap`s are introduced in Guava, they comply to Java's `Map` API, but with additional guarantees.

In a nutshell:

- you cannot add, replace or remove entries

  - they are "fully immutable" if entry objects do not have mutable state
  - as a consequence, they are thread safe
- `null`s are forbidden
- (slightly) more time- and space-efficient compared to usual Java's collections
- iteration order is predictable

For full info see [Guava's guide](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained#why) and [javadoc for `ImmutableCollection`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html) which applies to maps and other Guava's immutable collections.

Comment: You might add a link to https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained#why which also mentions "time and space savings".