# Java 8 map.replaceAll method throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, string, maps, replaceall

I am trying to replace ";" with ","

```
Map<String, String> params =// Random method
params.replaceAll((key, value) -> value.replaceAll(";", ","));
```

Line 2 throws below exception.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.replaceAll(Collections.java:1510)
```

I am trying to replace any semicolons in the values with a comma.

Comment: seems that your `value` is instance of `UnmodifiableMap` so you cannot modify it with modification operations like `replaceAll` since it would alter the map. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892350/immutable-vs-unmodifiable-collection) SO question.

Comment: `Splitter` is not a standard Java class... maybe post its code or state which library it is from - if `Guava`, documentation is clear: "... returns an **unmodifiable** map ..." (but who cares to RFM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see it in the error that it says *UnmodifiableMap*. You are using an unmodifiable collection, meaning that it is read only once you created it.

Looking at the source of the code it goes like:

```
public Map<String, String> split(CharSequence sequence) {
  Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
  for (String entry : outerSplitter.split(sequence)) {
    Iterator<String> entryFields = entrySplitter.splittingIterator(entry);

    checkArgument(entryFields.hasNext(), INVALID_ENTRY_MESSAGE, entry);
    String key = entryFields.next();
    checkArgument(!map.containsKey(key), "Duplicate key [%s] found.", key);

    checkArgument(entryFields.hasNext(), INVALID_ENTRY_MESSAGE, entry);
    String value = entryFields.next();
    map.put(key, value);

    checkArgument(!entryFields.hasNext(), INVALID_ENTRY_MESSAGE, entry);
  }
  return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

You can notice that it returns `Collections.unmodifiableMap(map)`.

To make it modifiable you can simply create a new instance of a HashMap for example:

```
Map paramMap = new HashMap<>(Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator(":").split(lineitem));
```

Answer (score 0):

as @NiVeR said, com.google.common.base.Splitter.split() is returning a unmodifiable map.

You can copy the unmodifiable map into a modifiable map just before starting to modifying values.

For instance;

```
Map paramMap = Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator(":").split(lineitem);
paramMap = Maps.newHashMap(paramMap);
paramMap.replaceAll((key, value) -> value.replaceAll(";", ","));
```