# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when calling List.remove(index)

Tags: java, arrays, list, exception, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why I get UnsupportedOperationException when trying to remove from the List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-i-get-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-from-the-list)

When I call List.remove(index) or list.remove(element) it raises a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. The only relevent error code is this:

```
17:08:10 [SEVERE]       at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
```

Here is an example:

```
String line = "cmd /say This is a test";
String[] segments = line.split(" ");
String cmd = segments[0];
List rest = Arrays.asList(segments);
rest.remove(0); // This line raises the exception
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? In my actuall code, I checked and there is a element at index 0 to be removed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)'s JavaDoc:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to
>   the returned list "write through" to the array.)

So instead of the fixed-size list:

```
List rest = Arrays.asList(segments);
```

create a new variable-size list:

```
List<String> rest = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(segments));
```