# Generics code remove not working

Tags: java, generics

I wanted to test some stuff out about generics in Java so I wrote a method using generics which takes a list and removes every other element. I wrote this method but it gives an UnsupportedOperationException error. What is the problem here?

```
    Integer[] strArray = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(strArray);
    removeOdd(numbers);
    for (Object o : numbers){
         System.out.println( o );
    }
}
        public static <T> void removeOdd ( List<T> list){
            Iterator<T> itr = list.iterator();
            int i = 0;

                while(itr.hasNext())
                {
                    itr.next();
                    i++;
                    if(i % 2 ==1){
                        itr.remove();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a `List` whose individual elements may be updated but the addition or removal of elements is not allowed. To create a variable size `List`, you can use:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strArray));
```

Comment: The returned list is backed by the array and may be modified. Calls to `set(int, E)` will successfully replace an element.

Comment: An element may be set but not removed

Comment: And thus the list is mutable. ;)

Answer (score 7):

[`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) creates a fixed sized list. You may replace an element, but not add or remove any.