# How to remove and set from List<String> in java?

Tags: java, list, loops

In java I have this function:

```
public List<String> seperatekeys(String text) {
    String[] keys = text.split("and");
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(keys);

    ListIterator<String> iter = words.listIterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String currentWord = iter.next().trim();
        if (currentWord.equals("")) {
            iter.remove();
        } else {
            iter.set(currentWord);
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```

But when I do a remove(), it crashes saying unsupportedoperationerror.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` returns a `List` that cannot be modified (at runtime)

Comment: why don't you try currentword.equals(null);

Comment: Pass the result of `Arrays.asList()` into the constructor of a different list

Comment: @shekhar: how will that help?

Comment: No,user3580294 is wrong here

Comment: Sometimes,"" causes no result , whereas nulls do the job!

Comment: @shekhar If you notice, the error is with `remove()`. I fail to see how comparing to `null` would fix that.

Comment: so your saying an empty string when compared to null will return a true?

Comment: Create an empty ArrayList, iterate over the array directly, adding those elements you want to keep instead

Comment: @user35...: That worked nicely, although seems inefficient...

Comment: @madprogrammer: seems ur answer will work the best.

Comment: `List<String> words = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(keys));` http://stackoverflow.com/a/2965808/3574819

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `Arrays#asList()` returns an `ArrayList` implementation that inherits `remove()` from `AbstractList`. The implementation of `remove()` in `AbstractList` is this:

```
public E remove(int index) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

And because the iterator uses the list's iterator to perform its `remove()` method, you end up with the exception.

You have a few solutions here. You can either pass the result of `Arrays#asList()` to an `ArrayList` constructor:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(keys));
```

Now, you can iterate over the resulting `List` and remove the elements you want.

Or, asMadProgrammer stated, you can take the opposite approach and iterate over the array and add the elements you want to keep:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : keys) {
    String currentWord = s.trim();
    if (!currentWord.equals("")) {
        words.add(currentWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it be `new ArrayList` instead of `new ArrayList<>`?

Comment: @user3580294-Nice answer!

Comment: @Unihedron No. The former is a raw type and should be avoided if at all possible. The latter is generic and is, for the most part, type-safe.

Comment: You're directly assigning it to a `List<String>`. The raw type is inferred to `<String>`.

Comment: @Unihedron No inference takes place when dealing with raw types, because no generic checks are performed at all.