# removing last element of list not working JAVA

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I'm doing my personal android calculator just for fun to learn Java and Android.

But the function is not working... the String list `operacoes` is where I have, in sequence the operators i will need (+,-,x and /). And the String list `numeros` is where I have the numbers to do the operations like for example: 32 45 232 12.

Maybe what I want to do in the code is hard to explain but I'll give it a try: I'm trying to do the x or / operations first and then reduce 1 element in `numeros` and `operacoes` list, and only after all of them are done I will go to + and - operations.

But it gives errors and I don't know what is wrong. Does someone has a clue?

The android compiler says:

```
 .UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
        at nunoprograms.com.nunoprogram.Operacoes.conta(Operacoes.java:54)
        at nunoprograms.com.nunoprogram.App2Activity.onClick(App2Activity.java:222)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

And code is:

```
public int conta(){

    int j,num1,num2,total=0;

    num1=Integer.parseInt(this.numeros.get(0));
       int x=this.operacoes.size();
       int y=0;

       for(int i=0;i<x-y;i++){//Objective: priority to x and / operations

        if(this.operacoes.get(i).equals("x")||this.operacoes.get(i).equals("/")) {
            if (this.operacoes.get(i).equals("x"))
                total = Integer.parseInt(this.numeros.get(i)) * Integer.parseInt(this.numeros.get(i+1));
            if (this.operacoes.get(i).equals("/"))
                total = Integer.parseInt(this.numeros.get(i)) / Integer.parseInt(this.numeros.get(i+1));

            this.numeros.set(i,String.valueOf(total));//atribui o valor da operaçao

            for (j=i;j<this.operacoes.size()-1;j++)this.numeros.set(j+1,this.numeros.get(j+2));
            for (j=i;j<this.operacoes.size()-1;j++)this.operacoes.set(j,this.operacoes.get(j+1));
            this.numeros.remove(this.numeros.size()-1);//remove last element
            this.operacoes.remove(this.operacoes.size()-1);
            y++;
        }
        }
    //now the + and - operations
    total=num1;
    for(int i=0;i<this.operacoes.size();i++) {

      num2=Integer.parseInt(this.numeros.get(i+1));
        System.out.println("conteudo da string de operacoes: "+ this.operacoes.get(i));

        if(this.operacoes.get(i).equals("+"))total+=num2;
        else if(this.operacoes.get(i).equals("-"))total-=num2;

    }
return total;
}
```

Operacoes Class:

```
public class Operacoes {

    private int numeros_size,operacoes_size;
    private List<String> numeros;
    private List<String> operacoes;

    Operacoes(List<String> x,int x_size, List<String> y, int y_size){
        this.numeros=x;
        this.numeros_size=x_size;
        this.operacoes=y;
        this.operacoes_size=y_size;
    }

    public int conta(){
    ...
    }

}
```

---

ADDED

I had to do this on the declaration of the String lists:

```
Operacoes(List<String> x,int x_size, List<String> y, int y_size){
    this.numeros=new ArrayList(x);
    this.numeros_size=x_size;
    this.operacoes=new ArrayList(y);
    this.operacoes_size=y_size;
}
```

It works now!

Comment: What happens when size is zero?

Comment: Can [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2965808/4762282) help you?

Comment: what size are you asking?

Comment: First of all: The compiler is not giving you that error, doesn't it? I mean, looks like a runtime something. Second and more important: I think you have an issue with the implementaiton of List you are using. Can you show us where you instantiating such collections?

Comment: This is not size related, what collection is used? Your own?

Comment: Can you provide declaration of "numeros" and "operacoes"?

Comment: which line is line number 54?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably working with an **immutable array**.

> The java.util.Arrays.ArrayList version is immutable and its remove()
>   method is not overridden. As such, it defers to the AbstractList
>   implementation of remove(), which throws an
>   UnsupportedOperationException.

Just see where you are creating the **"numeros" or the "operacoes" array**. If you want to work with a mutable array, instantiate a `java.util.ArrayList` instead to hold those values.

---

**ADDED**

In this class there must be a "numeros" and a "operacoes" class properties.
In the code snippet provided, it's not shown how they are created.

Find where they are instantiated, and use a `new Arraylist()`.

---

**ADDED**

Here is your constructor

```
Operacoes(List<String> x,int x_size, List<String> y, int y_size){
    this.numeros=x;
    this.numeros_size=x_size;
    this.operacoes=y;
    this.operacoes_size=y_size;
}
```

So you are receiving the `numeros` and `operacoes` as parameters.

The best way would be to see who is sending them and why they are immutable.

The easy way, just do this:

```
Operacoes(List<String> x,int x_size, List<String> y, int y_size){
    this.numeros= new ArrayList(x);
    this.numeros_size=x_size;
    this.operacoes= new ArrayList(y);
    this.operacoes_size=y_size;
}
```

Comment: this is how i created them:

Comment: private List<String> numeros;
private List<String> operacoes;