# Why I get UnsupportedOperationException in android?

Tags: android

```
public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

    public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();  
    public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;  
    public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;  

    public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {  
        headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);  
    }  

    public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {  
        this.headers.add(section);  
        this.sections.put(section, adapter); }  

    public Object getItem(int position) {  
       for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  
             // check if position inside this section   
            if(position <= 0) return section;  

          if(position < size){
                return adapter.getItem(position - 1);  
            }
            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  
    public int getCount() {  
        // total together all sections, plus one for each section header  
        int total = 0;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getCount() + 1;  
        return total;  
    }   
    public int getViewTypeCount() {  
        // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections  
        int total = 1;  
       for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        return total;  
    } public int getItemViewType(int position) {  
        int type = 1;  
       for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
           int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;  
            if(position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);  
           // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }  
    @Override  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        int sectionnum = 0;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  
            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
```

> Here is an Exception

```
        if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);                
        // otherwise jump into next section  
        position -= size;  
        sectionnum++;  
    }  
    return null;  
}
```

**I don't understand why i get this exception in this line...Please Help me~ 
I heard this problem causes by List<> but, I couldn't find what is wrong in my coding**

Comment: post your logcat please

Answer (score 0):

Where are you assigning a value to `headers`? What's most likely happening is that this is a `ArrayAdapter` backed by a read-only `ArrayList`.

This can happen for example when you run

```
this.headers = new ArrayAdapter(context, resource, Arrays.asList(T... array))
```

which returns a custom `Array.ArrayList` that is read-only. See [here for asList documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

This means you cannot run a `.add()` method on the list. For solution, see this [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-i-get-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-from-the-list).