# How to change List<String> value inside onOptionsItemSelected in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-menu

```
String[] klassen = {"3ECa1", "3ECa2", "3ECb", "3WEa", "3WEb", "3STWa", "3STWb", "3STWc"};
String[] klassen2 = {"4ECa", "4ECb", "4WE", "4STWa", "4STWb", "4STWc", "1Okan", "2Okan"};
String[] klassen3 = {"5EM", "5EW", "5MW", "5WW", "5STWa", "5STWb", "5STWc", "1Okan"};
String[] klassen4 = {"6EM", "6EW", "6MW", "6WW", "6STWa", "6STWb", "6STWc", "2Okan"};

List<String> klassenList = Arrays.asList(klassen);

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id){
        case R.id.jaren_3de:
            klassenList = Arrays.asList(klassen);
            break;
        case R.id.jaren_4de:
            klassenList = Arrays.asList(klassen2);
            break;
        case R.id.jaren_5de:
            klassenList = Arrays.asList(klassen3);
            break;
        case R.id.jaren_6de:
            klassenList = Arrays.asList(klassen4);
            break;

        // case R.id.

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

So I'm trying to change the value of the List klassenList inside my onOptionsItemSelected method.

```
R.id.jaren_*de
```

These are the menu items that I have to click to change the buttons on screen to the desired text (the klassen* arrays). The buttons are all done using an adapter, that needs

```
 List<String> klassenList;
```

This, however, isn't working. It isn't giving any errors (except a null exception error when I don't assign a value to klassenList, but I know why that happens). It just doesn't change the text of the buttons and I can't find any solution to it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are re-assigning a variable. the object you used for your buttons is no longer `klassenList`, you have to reset them

Comment: How would I go about doing this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You registered the initial `klassenlist` instance with the adapter, but your current code is just changing the value of your local `klassenlist` variable. The adapter is still referencing the initial `klassenlist` instance, so you need to update *that* instance's data.

This should work:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id){
        case R.id.jaren_3de:
            updateKlassenList(klassen);
            break; 
        case R.id.jaren_4de:
            updateKlassenList(klassen2);
            break; 
        case R.id.jaren_5de:
            updateKlassenList(klassen3);
            break; 
        case R.id.jaren_6de:
            updateKlassenList(klassen4);
            break; 

        // case R.id. 

    } 

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateKlassenList(String[] data) {
    klassenList.clear();
    klassenList.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));

    // I assume "adapter" is the adapter of interest.
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

NOTE: This code is not optimal, as it creates a new `List` object every time (via `Arrays.asList()`). But it should give you an idea of how to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm getting a "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" error now. I've looked it up and it has something to do with versions, but I have the latest so that couldn't be a problem.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out thanks to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-i-get-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-from-the-list I used a LinkedList instead of an ordinary List now, and it works!

Answer (score -1):

Have you notified your listview that data changed? Try

```
listViewAdapater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: obviously no, since the variable `klassenList` is re-assigned