# I am having a java.lang.unsupportedoperationexception in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-menu

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
int id = item.getItemId();

switch(id){
    case R.id.jaren_3de:
        updateKlassenList(klassen);
        break; 
    case R.id.jaren_4de:
        updateKlassenList(klassen2);
        break; 
    case R.id.jaren_5de:
        updateKlassenList(klassen3);
        break; 
    case R.id.jaren_6de:
        updateKlassenList(klassen4);
        break; 

    // case R.id. 

} 

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateKlassenList(String[] data) {
    klassenList.clear();
    klassenList.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));

    // I assume "adapter" is the adapter of interest.
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I added the method:

```
private void updateKlassenList(String[] data) {
    klassenList.clear();
    klassenList.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));

    // I assume "adapter" is the adapter of interest.
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

to fix a previous problem (see [How to change List<String> value inside onOptionsItemSelected in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686505/how-to-change-liststring-value-inside-onoptionsitemselected-in-android-studio)), but now I am getting a Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationsException. I've been looking it up and it seems it has something to do with outdated versions, but I recently updated everything.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is the error I'm getting:

```
01-10 16:08:23.508 1457-1457/com.geesplit.lessenrooster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.geesplit.lessenrooster, PID: 1457
                                                                      java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                                                                          at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
                                                                          at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
                                                                          at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:658)
                                                                          at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:466)
                                                                          at com.geesplit.lessenrooster.MainActivity.updateKlassenList(MainActivity.java:112)
                                                                          at com.geesplit.lessenrooster.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:95)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1133)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(SubMenuBuilder.java:81)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:186)
                                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3872)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3637)
                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2399)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
                                                                          at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:1731)
                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5807)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5781)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5752)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5897)
                                                                          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                          at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, along with the Java code that triggers the stack trace.

Comment: The type of your `List` does not support removals - are you using an unmodifiable list? Log the class of `klassenList` and post the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to this thread: [Why do I get an UnsupportedOperationException when trying to remove an element from a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-i-get-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-from-the-list)
I used a LinkedList instead of an ordinary List now, and it works!

Comment: Good, and this answer can be useful to others. You should flag it as accepted!

Comment: I need to wait 2 days before flagging my own answer as accepted, I tried it already :)

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't know that (or I forgot) :)

Answer (score 0):

I got to know that I was using this without initialization, so I initialized like this:

```
//globadl varaible:
private List<ModelClass> ModelDataList;

//code where Used this List.
DataList = new LinkedList<>();
```

This solved my problem.