# Expression Solver Algorithm with Java

Tags: java, expression, solver

I am trying to create a program that will take in an expression as a String and solve it. So if the input is  3 + 5 it would return 8. I have done majority of the coding, but I'm not sure why I keep getting an UnsupportedOperationExpression in Java. Please help if you can!

** Also I have to use ArrayLists on this assignment because I have not yet learned lists. Here is my current code so far:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FirstPart {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String sampleString = "1 + 2 + 3 / 2 + 1";
      String[] items = sampleString.split(" ");
      List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList(items);
      System.out.println(itemList);
      for(int zz=0; zz<itemList.size(); zz++)
        if(itemList.get(zz).equals("*"))
           {itemList.set(zz-1,Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(itemList.get(zz-1))*Integer.parseInt(itemList.get(zz+1)))));
           itemList.remove(zz+1);
           itemList.remove(zz);
           zz--;}
        else if(itemList.get(zz).equals("/"))
           {itemList.set(zz-1,Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(itemList.get(zz-1))/Integer.parseInt(itemList.get(zz+1)))));
           itemList.remove(zz+1);
           itemList.remove(zz);
           zz--;}
      for(int zz=0; zz<itemList.size(); zz++)
        if(itemList.get(zz).equals("+"))
           {itemList.set(zz-1,Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(itemList.get(zz-1))+Integer.parseInt(itemList.get(zz+1)))));
           itemList.remove(zz+1);
           itemList.remove(zz);
           zz--;}
        else if(itemList.get(zz).equals("-"))
           {itemList.set(zz-1,Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(itemList.get(zz-1))+Integer.parseInt(itemList.get(zz+1)))));
           itemList.remove(zz+1);
           itemList.remove(zz);
           zz--;}
      System.out.println(itemList);
   }
   }
```

Thanks again if you can help!

Comment: You are trying to write an interpreter / compiler for a trivial language.  Infix, however, is a very tricky notation to handle, as either prefix (+ 3 5) or postfix (5 3 +) are much easier (stack based).  That said, what line does your UnsupportedOperationExpression error occur on?

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-i-get-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-from-the-list

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you construct a `List` from an array like this

```
List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList(items)
```

the returned list does not allow to remove an item from the list

```
itemList.remove(zz + 1); // throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Instead, create an empty list which supports removal and add all the array elements to it:

```
List<String> itemList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
java.util.Collections.addAll(itemList, items);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I actually did something else because when I tried to do this it gave me an error about the <>.

Comment: @SorinCirca because you are using a Java JDK < 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Try reading about reverse polish notation algorithm. It seems to do exactly what you need, you only have to implement it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation