# Adding a string to a static ArrayList in another class resulted in UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android

My goal is to create an ArrayList that can be accessed from any activity in the application, so I created a class with static ArrayList<>:

```
public class CategoryArrayList {
    public static String id;
    public static List<String> category_spinner_user = new ArrayList<>();

public static void addCategory_spinner_user(String stringToBeAdded) {
        CategoryArrayList.category_spinner_user.add(stringToBeAdded);
    }
```

and then try to add an item to it by a call through an Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button button;
        public void testClicked(View view){
            CategoryArrayList.category_spinner_user.add("AAA");
        }  
}
```

ฺBut it resulted in an FATAL_EXCEPTION error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Catching exception resulted in the same error report:

> W/System.err: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
> at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)

Changing ArrayList<> to LinkedList<> (as suggested in [Why do I get an UnsupportedOperationException when trying to remove an element from a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-do-i-get-an-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-an-element-f)) does not help either.

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you ever let `category_spinner_user = Arrays.asList(XXX)` at somewhere?

Comment: you can also do this.. `CategoryArrayList.category_spinner_user = new Arraylist<>;` then `.add("AAA");`
        }

Answer (score 2):

Try code below for layout and attention that define function name of android:onClick the same function name **testClicked(View view)** in TestActivity

```
<Button
    android:onClick="testClicked"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="add"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend to use safe solution for view click with click listener:

```
View(your button).setOnClickListener(... ...);
```

Some brand devices could crash for using 'android:onClick= ...' in view layout.

Comment: Thank you for your heads up