# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException with ArrayList()

Tags: java

I have a class like this

```
@Getter
public class MyClass  {

    private Collection<String> headers;

    public myConfig(DownloadRequest downloadRequest) {

        this.headers = downloadRequest.getHeaders() == null ? new ArrayList() : downloadRequest.getHeaders();
    }
 }
```

When I run this it gives me `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

As I use headers in another function and do `getHeaders().clear()`, I get this error.

Return type of `downloadRequest.getHeaders()` is `Collection<String>`

I am unable to figure out what I can cast the headers to.

I keep getting different Exceptions as I change my code, like `UnsupportedOperationException` and `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList incompatible with java.util.ArrayList`, when I change the code to something else, trying out other StackOverflow solutions like this - [Why do I get an UnsupportedOperationException when trying to remove an element from a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-do-i-get-an-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-an-element-f).

I have just started working on Java and have been working more on python and nodejs in the past.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `new ArrayList<String>(downloadRequest.getHeaders())` to convert it

Comment: @azro Yes that works, not getting an error with it, can accept it in some time

Comment: It's bad coding style to use a getter to update another object's collection field. You should create a clearHeaders() method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Collection#clear()`, as [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#clear()) is an optional operation and not all implementations need to support it. If they do not, they can throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. In your case, the list returned from `downloadRequest.getHeaders()` is apparently an unmodifiable collection which does not support this operation.

If it did, calling `clear()` on it would remove all headers from the `downloadRequest`. Is that what you're trying to achieve? Probably not. If yes, instead there should be a method like `downloadRequest.clearHeaders()`.

To work around this problem, you can copy the elements out of an unmodifiable collection into e.g. an `ArrayList`:

```java
new ArrayList<>(downloadRequest.getHeaders())
```

This copies the elements out of the original container into a new modifiable `ArrayList` that you can then modify however you like.

---

Also note you're mentioning `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` which is *named* `ArrayList`, but it is not `java.util.ArrayList`. This is an unresizable collection returned from `Arrays.asList(...)` and it does not support `clear()` either.

Comment: One last remark is that `downloadRequest.getHeaders()` should never return `null` in a good design. Methods returning `null` instead of an empty collection are a code smell and should only be used when null is different from an empty collection. (Actually in that case you're better of with some kind of a specialized class, but that's a different discussion.)

Answer (score 2):

The `downloadRequest.getHeaders()` method may return a Collection that is read-only and so doesn't support `.clear()`

You may use an `ArrayList` to wrap it and get a write-accessible structure

```
// private list<String> headers;


Collection<String> headers = downloadRequest.getHeaders();
this.headers = headers  == null ? new ArrayList<>() : new ArrayList<>(headers) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using the wrong ArrayList class when doing new ArrayList()

From your ClassCastException you are using :
java.util.Arrays$ArrayList, which is a nested class of the Arrays class and is immutable.

Check your import : you should be using java.util.ArrayList.

Edit : never mind this nested class is private; previous answer is probably right, the collection returned must be immutable.