# How to iterate over object array from hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two hashmap of type

```
Hashmap<String,Object[]> hasOne = new Hashmap<String,Object[]>();
Hashmap<String,Object[]> hasTwo = new Hashmap<String,Object[]>();
```

I've added values in both of them,

```
hasOne.put("anyKey", new Object[1,"Two",3.14]);
hasTwo.put("anyKey", new Object[1,"Two"]);
```

My requirement is I need to compare values from the object array of both hashmaps and need to print missing data from the object array of the second hashmap ( Ex. **3.14** is missing in the second array on comparing `new Object[1,"Two",3.14]` && `new Object[1,"Two"]` ).

Using `Arrays.asList(hasOne.get("anyKey"));`// will get details of object array but i'm not sure how to iterate over that array.

PFB code snippet

```
Map<String, Object[]> one = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
Map<String, Object[]> two = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
one.put("firstArray", new Object[]  {1, "Two", 3.14});
two.put("secondArray", new Object[] {1, "Two"});
for(int k=0;k<one.size();k++)
{   
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(one.get("firstArray")));
}
```

Comment: By the way, your use of an array of `Object` smells like a design problem that should be addressed by defining a class. Java 16 makes this easier with its [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature if the main purpose of your class is to communicate data transparently and immutably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
References I used are :

1. https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-compare-two-arraylist-in-java
2. [Why do I get an UnsupportedOperationException when trying to remove an element from a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-do-i-get-an-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-an-element-f)

```
        // create and insert into maps
        Map<String, Object[]> one = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
        Map<String, Object[]> two = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
   
        one.put("firstArray", new Object[]  {1, "Two", 3.14});
        two.put("secondArray", new Object[] {1, "Two"});

        for(int k=0;k<one.size();k++)
        {
            List<Object> arrList1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(one.get("firstArray"))); // get the value from the map "one" as arrayList
            List<Object> arrList2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(two.get("secondArray"))); // get the value from the map "two" as arrayList
            // System.out.println(arrList1 + " " + arrList2);
            arrList1.removeAll(arrList2); // removes all different values as you require
            System.out.println(arrList1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is that for each key in the first map you want to find any objects in the value array which are not in the second map:

```
for (String entry: one.entrySet()) {
    for (Object val: entry.getValue()) {
        if (Arrays.stream(two.get(entry.getKey()).noneMatch(val::equals))) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can do all this in nested streams but explicit `for` loops are easier to understand.